# Best way to find if an item is in a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the best way to find if an object is in an array?

This is the best way I know:

```js
function include(arr, obj) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == obj) return true;
  }
}

console.log(include([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)); // true
console.log(include([1, 2, 3, 4], 6)); // undefined
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25765186/1320932

Comment: 2 things: 1.) 'include' is a really bad name for a function that does not modify the state of anything.  It's especially bad for a function that simply returns a boolean. 2.) You need to add "return(false);" before the end of the function.

Comment: as of ECMAScript 2016, you can use Array.prototype.includes function: 
myArray.includes(3); // true

Comment: In ES6 you can do something like arr.find(lamda function) , example:  [1, 2, 3,4,5].find(x => x == 3). if element is found it is returned else undefined is returned

Comment: arr.some(element => element === obj); some is the bestway because when it finds an item and then break the loop.

Answer (score 768, accepted):

As of ECMAScript 2016 you can use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
arr.includes(obj);
```

If you want to support IE or other older browsers:

```
function include(arr,obj) {
    return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
}
```

EDIT:
This will not work on IE6, 7 or 8 though. The best workaround is to define it yourself if it's not present:

1. [Mozilla's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (ECMA-262) version:

   ```
      if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
      {

           Array.prototype.indexOf = function(searchElement /*, fromIndex */)

        {


        "use strict";

        if (this === void 0 || this === null)
          throw new TypeError();

        var t = Object(this);
        var len = t.length >>> 0;
        if (len === 0)
          return -1;

        var n = 0;
        if (arguments.length > 0)
        {
          n = Number(arguments[1]);
          if (n !== n)
            n = 0;
          else if (n !== 0 && n !== (1 / 0) && n !== -(1 / 0))
            n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));
        }

        if (n >= len)
          return -1;

        var k = n >= 0
              ? n
              : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0);

        for (; k < len; k++)
        {
          if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement)
            return k;
        }
        return -1;
      };

    }
   ```
2. [Daniel James](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-an-item-in-a-javascript-array#144172)'s version:

   ```
    if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
      Array.prototype.indexOf = function (obj, fromIndex) {
        if (fromIndex == null) {
            fromIndex = 0;
        } else if (fromIndex < 0) {
            fromIndex = Math.max(0, this.length + fromIndex);
        }
        for (var i = fromIndex, j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
            if (this[i] === obj)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
      };
    }
   ```
3. [roosteronacid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-an-item-in-a-javascript-array#144664)'s version:

   ```
    Array.prototype.hasObject = (
      !Array.indexOf ? function (o)
      {
        var l = this.length + 1;
        while (l -= 1)
        {
            if (this[l - 1] === o)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
      } : function (o)
      {
        return (this.indexOf(o) !== -1);
      }
    );
   ```

Comment: I'm curious as to why your version of the Mozilla function is so different from the website you're linking to. Did you modify it yourself or is it just an old version or something?

Comment: @Shenjoku: "answered Sep 27 '08 at 15:45"

Comment: Well, there's my answer haha. I can't tell if there's an older version just by looking at the mozilla website so I wasn't sure. Not that it matters, just a curiosity. In any case this was still helpful so you get an upvote ;)

Comment: @Vinko Vrsalovic Yes, it is a good solution, but you should hide embedded implementation indexOf() function which returns -1 with ~ operator: function include(arr,obj) { return !!(~arr.indexOf(obj)) ; }

Comment: but, since when is indexOf compatible with IE, because I found it is compatible with IE https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: @VinkoVrsalovic 
how do I modify this function 

function include(arr,obj) {
    return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
}

To return true or false when passing it multiple values like maybe two strings? :D

Comment: Another option is to use .find() more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62305136/19276480

Answer (score 210):

If you are using jQuery:

```
$.inArray(5 + 5, [ "8", "9", "10", 10 + "" ]);
```

For more information: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: Note that "inArray" is a misnomer, because it doesn't return boolean value - it returns index of first element found. So if you are checking if element exists you should use `if (-1 != $.inArray(...)) ...`.

Comment: Helpful, but I don't think it's an appropriate answer here. The question is tagged "javascript" indicating "vanilla" in my opinion. :)

Answer (score 34):

First, implement `indexOf` in JavaScript for browsers that don't already have it. For example, see [Erik Arvidsson's array extras](http://erik.eae.net/playground/arrayextras/arrayextras.js) (also, the [associated blog post](http://erik.eae.net/archives/2005/06/05/17.53.19/)). And then you can use `indexOf` without worrying about browser support. Here's a slightly optimised version of his `indexOf` implementation:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (obj, fromIndex) {
        if (fromIndex == null) {
            fromIndex = 0;
        } else if (fromIndex < 0) {
            fromIndex = Math.max(0, this.length + fromIndex);
        }
        for (var i = fromIndex, j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
            if (this[i] === obj)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    };
}
```

It's changed to store the length so that it doesn't need to look it up every iteration. But the difference isn't huge. A less general purpose function might be faster:

```
var include = Array.prototype.indexOf ?
    function(arr, obj) { return arr.indexOf(obj) !== -1; } :
    function(arr, obj) {
        for(var i = -1, j = arr.length; ++i < j;)
            if(arr[i] === obj) return true;
        return false;
    };
```

I prefer using the standard function and leaving this sort of micro-optimization for when it's really needed. But if you're keen on micro-optimization I adapted the [benchmarks](https://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/resource/loop-test.html) that roosterononacid linked to in the comments, to [benchmark searching in arrays](http://obscurity.nfshost.com/x/bench.html). They're pretty crude though, a full investigation would test arrays with different types, different lengths and finding objects that occur in different places.

Comment: The code examples you are linking to are slow on large arrays. See the comments in my implementation example of a hasItem() function.

Comment: Take a look at these benchmarks: http://blogs.sun.com/greimer/resource/loop-test.htm For-loops are slow. But I guess the arrays used in the benchmarks are pretty huge :)

Comment: http://blogs.sun.com/greimer/resource/loop-test.html

Comment: I agree. I'm also quite pragmatic. But in the case of optimizing the very basics of the language, I think it's good design to implement functionality as performance-effective as possible.

Comment: use mozilla Array.indexOf polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill

Answer (score 13):

If the array is unsorted, there isn't really a better way (aside from using the above-mentioned indexOf, which I think amounts to the same thing).  If the array is sorted, you can do a binary search, which works like this:

1. Pick the middle element of the array.
2. Is the element you're looking for bigger than the element you picked?  If so, you've eliminated the bottom half of the array.  If it isn't, you've eliminated the top half.
3. Pick the middle element of the remaining half of the array, and continue as in step 2, eliminating halves of the remaining array.  Eventually you'll either find your element or have no array left to look through.

Binary search runs in time proportional to the logarithm of the length of the array, so it can be much faster than looking at each individual element.

Comment: You probably should mention that this approach would be faster on large, sorted arrays than small ones.

Comment: why would this be slower on smaller arrays?

Comment: @vidstige: He means it scales well, but isn't necessarily fastest for small inputs.

Comment: This runs in O(lg n) as opposed to O(n), which is way more scalable

Answer (score 10):

**[ ].has(obj)**

assuming `.indexOf()` is implemented

```
Object.defineProperty( Array.prototype,'has',
{
    value:function(o, flag){
    if (flag === undefined) {
        return this.indexOf(o) !== -1;
    } else {   // only for raw js object
        for(var v in this) {
            if( JSON.stringify(this[v]) === JSON.stringify(o)) return true;
        }
        return false;                       
    },
    // writable:false,
    // enumerable:false
})
```

!!! do not make `Array.prototype.has=function(){...` because you'll add an enumerable element in every array and js is broken.

```
//use like          
[22 ,'a', {prop:'x'}].has(12) // false
["a","b"].has("a") //  true

[1,{a:1}].has({a:1},1) // true
[1,{a:1}].has({a:1}) // false
```

the use of 2nd arg (flag) forces  comparation by value instead of reference

comparing raw objects

```
[o1].has(o2,true) // true if every level value is same
```

Answer (score 8):

It depends on your purpose. If you program for the Web, avoid `indexOf`, it isn't supported by Internet Explorer 6 (lot of them still used!), or do conditional use:

```
if (yourArray.indexOf !== undefined) result = yourArray.indexOf(target);
else result = customSlowerSearch(yourArray, target);
```

`indexOf` is probably coded in native code, so it is faster than anything you can do in JavaScript (except binary search/dichotomy if the array is appropriate).
Note: it is a question of taste, but I would do a `return false;` at the end of your routine, to return a true Boolean...

Comment: ha...I shrill to think there's still an IE6 client out there at this point...

Comment: shouldn't there be a "as of 2008" like in wikipedia page so that people know this statement is certainly outdated

Comment: @allan.simon Look at my icon (and stats) at the bottom of my answer. Just above, there is "answered Sep 27 '08 at 16:28". It is called a date, and people used to Stack Overflow look at these dates to take answers with a grain of salt...
That said, my local public library still has IE6 installed on their computers! (but somebody installed Chrome, fortunately!)

Answer (score 6):

Here's some meta-knowledge for you - if you want to know what you can do with an Array, check the documentation - here's the Array page for Mozilla

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

There you'll see reference to indexOf, added in Javascript 1.6

Comment: Weird URL for a manual containing information about Javascript 1.8 and beyond! :)

Comment: this doesnt cover object arrays like the author asked about

Comment: @VinkoVrsalovic: the URL has changed to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 5):

A robust way to check if an object is an array in javascript is detailed here:

Here are two functions from the [xa.js](http://xajs.chalmershouse.com) framework which I attach to a `utils = {}` ‘container’. These should help you properly detect arrays.

```
var utils = {};

/**
 * utils.isArray
 *
 * Best guess if object is an array.
 */
utils.isArray = function(obj) {
     // do an instanceof check first
     if (obj instanceof Array) {
         return true;
     }
     // then check for obvious falses
     if (typeof obj !== 'object') {
         return false;
     }
     if (utils.type(obj) === 'array') {
         return true;
     }
     return false;
 };

/**
 * utils.type
 *
 * Attempt to ascertain actual object type.
 */
utils.type = function(obj) {
    if (obj === null || typeof obj === 'undefined') {
        return String (obj);
    }
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)
        .replace(/\[object ([a-zA-Z]+)\]/, '$1').toLowerCase();
};
```

If you then want to check if an object is in an array, I would also include this code:

```
/**
 * Adding hasOwnProperty method if needed.
 */
if (typeof Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty !== 'function') {
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = function (prop) {
        var type = utils.type(this);
        type = type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.substr(1);
        return this[prop] !== undefined
            && this[prop] !== window[type].prototype[prop];
    };
}
```

And finally this in_array function:

```
function in_array (needle, haystack, strict) {
    var key;

    if (strict) {
        for (key in haystack) {
            if (!haystack.hasOwnProperty[key]) continue;

            if (haystack[key] === needle) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (key in haystack) {
            if (!haystack.hasOwnProperty[key]) continue;

            if (haystack[key] == needle) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.  Also, when you copy/paste the same link-only answer to several very old questions at once, it just looks like spam.

Comment: Sorry Bill, I really didn't mean it to seem like spam and was just trying to update a few of the old questions about this topic too. I've edited the post here to include the actual answer instead of linking off.

Comment: @Bill, actually re-reading the question, this doesn't even answer it at all. I must have made a mistake.