# How to refer to object fields with a variable?

Tags: javascript

Let's asume that I have an object:

```
var obj = {"A":"a", "B":"b", "x":"y", "a":"b"}
```

When I want to refer to "A" I just write `obj.A`

How to do it when I have key in a variable, i.e.:

```
var key = "A";
```

Is there any *function* that returns a value or `null` (if key isn't in the object)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use bracket notation, like this:

```
var key = "A";
var value = json[key];
```

In JavaScript these two are equivalent:

```
object.Property
object["Property"];
```

And just to be clear, this isn't JSON specific, JSON is just a specific subset of object notation...this works on any JavaScript object.  The result will be `undefined` if it's not in the object, [you can try all of this here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/qAMSJ/).

Comment: +1. Note though that the two forms you mentioned are equivalent _only if the Property is not a reserved word_... of which there are many in JS, and quite a few are unexpected. So in that sense `object["Property"]` is safer. OTOH, `object.Property` has the advantage (when `Property` is known statically) that tools like JSLint can run checks on them.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
json[key]
```

Try:

```
json.hasOwnProperty(key)
```

for the second part of your question (see [Checking if a key exists in a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-an-associative-array-key-exists-in-javascript))