# How to fill in the JSON in cycle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to have similar JSON structure:

```
{
    "group1": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "group2": ["C", "D", "E"],
    "group3": ["F", "G", "H"]
}
```

and need to create it in cycle:

```
courses.each(function(index) {
    name = $(this).attr("href").replace(/([^\/]*)\/.*/, "$1");
    prefix = $(this).attr("href").replace(/[^\/]*\/(.*)/, "$1");

    if (subjects.indexOf(prefix) == -1) {
        subjects[prefix] = new Array();
    }

    subjects[prefix].push(name);
});
```

The courses variable is DOM object from sth like this:

```
<a href="group1/A">...
<a href="group1/B">...
<a href="group2/D">...
```

After the cycle execution, it contents sth like this:

```
[Array[0], "group1", "group2"]
```

not the structure mentioned above...

Why?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what your question is?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-an-associative-array-key-exists-in-javascript (what I think you are going after with `.indexOf`).

Comment: the generated structure and needed structure aren't same, the question is why and how to fix it to get needed structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem stems from two things:

1. You're using `indexOf()` where you should be checking if an index is `in` an object
2. Your `name` regex is checking for the prefix and your `prefix` regex is testing for your name

So in order to solve this, you need to use this code:

```
courses.each(function(index) {
    var prefix = $(this).attr("href").replace(/([^\/]*)\/.*/, "$1"),
        name = $(this).attr("href").replace(/[^\/]*\/(.*)/, "$1");

    if (!(prefix in subjects)) { //here test using the "in" operator
        subjects[prefix] = []; //shorthand array notation
    }

    subjects[prefix].push(name);
});
```

You can see a working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ErUvC/1/