# Detect if an Object has children in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

In JavaScript you can get the children of an XML node like this...

```
var children = xml.childeNodes;
```

How do I get the children of an object?

```
var obj = {
  prop1: 'stuff',
  prop2: 'things',
  prop3: 'stuff-n-things'
}
```

---

### Round two

Given an object like so..

```
var Obj = {
  levelOneProp1: 'stuff',
  levelOneProp2: 'things',
  levelOneProp3: {
     levelTwoProp1: 'moreStuff',
     levelTwoProp2: 'morethings',
     levelTwoProp3: 'morestuff-n-things'
  } 
}
```

I would like to know which properties in `Obj` have children so I can loop through them in a recursive manner.  The goal is to be able to supply a dataset with an (theoretically) unlimited number of children and apply their values to input elements... Here is what I have so far.

```
function applyData( dataSet ){
    var hasChildren = false;

    for(var i = 0; i < dataSet.childNodeArrayGoesHere.length; i++){
        if(dataSet.detectChildNodesHere){
            hasChildren = true;
        }
    }

    if(hasChildren){
        for(var j = 0; j < dataSet.childNodeArrayGoesHere.length; i++){
            applyData(dataSet[j]);
        }
    } else {
        //apply the key/value pair to an input element

        $("input[name" + dataSet.propertyName + "]").val(dataSet.propertyValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refrain from drastically changing the context of a question. When you do this, you're rendering some of the existing answers useless. Try creating another question instead.

Comment: @ates - i kindof understand where u are going with this but the question was just clarified IMO.  I still just need the collection of "child nodes" to complete my function.

Comment: I just need to detect if a property is an "end node" essentially... sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 7):

You can iterate over all properties of an object [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/5Nsw7/):

```
var o = { prop1: 'this is prop 1', prop2: 'this is prop2'};

for(var propName in o) {
    if(o.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
        alert(o[propName]);   
    }
}
```

The `hasOwnProperty()` function checks to make sure that the specified property actually exists in the object.  Using it in this context makes sure you don't get any inherited properties.

Comment: The `for(var i in o)` loop does work to iterate through the entirety of the object, but if you read my edits see that I am... essentially... trying to detect if something is an `End Node` or not in order to apply it to an input field

Comment: This does not read the child elements if present. I do not have an answer yet to add any other suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

You can iterate over all properties of an object recursively [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/6tkeL6cf/1/).

Find all the end nodes, select the corresponding input tags by the name and put the value in it.

I used an object with just two levels, but it can be used with an object of n levels.

```
var Obj = {
          id1: 'stuff',
          id2: 'things',
          id3: {
              levelTwo1: 'moreStuff',
              levelTwo2: 'morethings',
              levelTwo3: 'morestuff-n-things'
          }
      }

function addAttributeInput(obj) {
    for (var o in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[o] == "object") {
            addAttributeInput(obj[o]);
        } else {
            $("input[name='" + o + "']").val(obj[o]);
        }
    }
}

addAttributeInput(Obj);
```

Answer (score 4):

This code detect whether `obj` has any child

```
Object.keys(obj).length
```

Comment: This seem to be the only answer that addresses the specific question.

Comment: The only relevant answer of all the answers on this page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not children, You have created an associative array.

Access them like this:

```
obj[prop1]
```

Comment: Technically, Javascript doesn't have associative arrays at all.  Just regular arrays and objects.

Comment: True, in this case it's an object that is being used as an associative array.

Answer (score -3):

What you're looking for are actually object keys. You can check if a object key exists by calling it:

**your obj:**

```
var obj = {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2
}
```

**check if undefined:**

```
if (obj.prop3 === undefined) {
    alert('obj key does not exist');
} else {
    alert(obj.prop3);
}
```

**or**

```
if (obj["prop3"] === undefined) {
    alert('obj key does not exist');
} else {
    alert(obj["prop3"]);
}
```

or if you face a use case where a obj key's value might be set to undefined manually:

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty("prop3")) {
    alert(obj["prop3"])
} else {
    alert('obj key does not exist');
}
```

Comment: `obj.key3 === undefined` is not a good way to check for existence of properties: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-an-associative-array-key-exists-in-javascript/1098955#1098955

Comment: i think that manually setting a obj key's value to undefined is far away from best practice

Comment: There are at least 16 people who disagree with you (see the comments to my answer). There are very real use cases where a property can be set to `undefined`. The property can also be set to `null`, in which case comparison to `undefined` will yield a match.