# Reading JSON Name and Value

Tags: json

I want to read JSON objects's name value pair.
Sample JSON below:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "**menuitem**": [
      {"**value**": "New", "**onclick**": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}
```

As an example, if I want to read name "menuitem" and its values "value", "onclick".
How is "menuitem" referred in this context?

Answer (score 1):

`menu.popup.menuitem[0].value`

`menu.popup.menuitem[0].onclick`

(you could also run through a loop if you wanted to get something rather than the first menuitem)

I assume there was asterisks in your code because you were trying to bold the sections in the json that you wanted to retrieve?

Also that json isn't valid, you're missing a closing `}`

Comment: yes.. those asterisks were to bold them.. 
btw, the answer u have provided is to retrieve menuitem's values (value, onclick).. but how can i retrieve menuitem itself..?

Comment: `menu.popup.menuitem[0]` it will return an array

Comment: how can i identify that there is a name "menuitem" under popup? how can i retrieve "menuitem" which is under popup?

Comment: if you want to check if key actually exists, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-an-associative-array-key-exists-in-javascript