# is there an equalant to PHP array_key_exists in javascript or jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking if an associative array key exists in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-an-associative-array-key-exists-in-javascript)

I have a PHP code block . For a purpose I am converting this to a JavaScript block.

I have PHP

```
if(array_key_exists($val['preferenceIDTmp'], $selected_pref_array[1]))
```

now I want to do this in jQuery. Is there any built in function to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-an-associative-array-key-exists-in-javascript seems to give you a couple of options

Comment: Please refer to this post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-an-associative-array-key-exists-in-javascript

Comment: This question is also about numeric array, so, not JSON object.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note that objects (with named properties) and associative arrays are the same thing in javascript.

You can use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty) to check if an object contains a given property:

```
o = new Object();  
o.prop = 'exists'; // or o['prop'] = 'exists', this is equivalent 

function changeO() {  
  o.newprop = o.prop;  
  delete o.prop;  
}  

o.hasOwnProperty('prop');   //returns true  
changeO();  
o.hasOwnProperty('prop');   //returns false
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
if (prop in object)
```

The subtle difference is that the latter checks the prototype chain.

Comment: The question is bout traditional arrays also, it work for Array()?

Answer (score 6):

In Javascript....

```
if(nameofarray['preferenceIDTmp'] != undefined) {
    // It exists
} else {
    // Does not exist
}
```

Comment: You want to check for undefined with === or !== otherwise you'll get false positives for null and false.

Answer (score 2):

http://phpjs.org/functions/array_key_exists:323

This is a great site for PHP programmers moving to js.