# define an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

how would you define an array in JavaScript like the one below and retrieve values by doing a search for country and gets the list of region.

```
region['US'] = {'Region 1': 'East', 'Region 2': 'West'}
```

Comment: You have listed an object, not an array. In JavaScript, arrays with string keys are always objects.

Comment: [JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays, but you can create an abstract object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1098040/901048) which basically behaves the same way.

Comment: You would need to use JSON and JSON's dot notation to retrieve data.

Comment: @Lix: All keys in JavaScript are strings... just to be clear. All arrays are always objects.

Comment: @squint if it is an `Array` then the `keys` are just the index in the array.  That's what he is talking about.

Comment: @squ - `var a = ['foo','bar']; var index=0; index++; console.log(a[index])`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Lix Only that `index` is converted to a string when used in the `[]` operator. Using `"0"` would work just the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we declare specific classes for the Country and the Region, this should work:

```
var Region = function(data) {
 var self = this;
 self.name = data.name || "";
}

var Country = function(data) {
 var self = this;
 self.name = data.name || "";
 self.regions = new Array();
}

var countries = {};
countries["US"] = new Country({ "name" : "US" });
countries["US"].regions.push(new Region({ "name" : "Region 1"}));
countries["US"].regions.push(new Region({ "name" : "Region 2"}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You want an object, not an array.  Objects have string keys, arrays have numeric keys only.

```
var region = {
  US: {'Region 1': 'East', 'Region 2': 'West'},
  UK: {'Region 1': 'East', 'Region 2': 'West'}

}
```

then get it with

```
region['US']
```

or

```
region.US
```