# Checking if a key exists in a JS object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JavaScript object:

```
var obj = {
    "key1" : val,
    "key2" : val,
    "key3" : val
}
```

Is there a way to check if a key exists in the array, similar to this?

```
testArray = jQuery.inArray("key1", obj);
```

does not work.

Do I have to iterate through the obj like this?

```
jQuery.each(obj, function(key,val)){}
```

Comment: js - object literal :) (not jQuery object)

Comment: True ;), shows that I don't have a js background - started with the jQuery library right from the start, and I believe I need to learn the basics...

Comment: `obj.has("key1")` will work if you are using ES6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a key exists in a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @Diablo I think you're trying to say `obj.hasOwnProperty("key1")` instead of just `has`?

Comment: @AminuKano Yes, you're right. I meant `obj.hasOwnProperty("key1")` . I simply overlooked my comment before pasting it here!

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

```
testArray = 'key1' in obj;
```

---

Sidenote: What you got there, is actually no jQuery object, but just a plain JavaScript Object.

Comment: Can we check not `in` like this ?

Comment: @SagarPanchal What do you mean? Something like `testArray = !( 'key1' in obj);`?

Answer (score 63):

That's not a jQuery object, it's just an object.

You can use the hasOwnProperty method to check for a key:

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty("key1")) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: you should not use it. it is said to be slow . best way is to use 'key' in object

Comment: @hannadrehman Can you give me a reference to the doc/article where it is mentioned? :)

Comment: @Fan_of_Martijn_Pieters i follow strict ESlint rule set. it is mentioned there as one of the rules.https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins

Comment: @hannadrehman Don't use the key-in-object, it can be plain wrong, this is the best way.

Comment: Downvoted because this does not work when detecting keys with a null value. For example, if the value of obj["key1"] == null (so key1 exists in obj and its value is null), this will return a false result that key1 is not in obj.

Comment: @user1258361: You are mistaken. If the key exists in the object the `hasOwnProperty` method will return `true` even if the value of the property is null.

Answer (score 9):

```
var obj = {
    "key1" : "k1",
    "key2" : "k2",
    "key3" : "k3"
};

if ("key1" in obj)
    console.log("has key1 in obj");
```

=========================================================================

To access a child key of another key

```
var obj = {
    "key1": "k1",
    "key2": "k2",
    "key3": "k3",
    "key4": {
        "keyF": "kf"
    }
};

if ("keyF" in obj.key4)
    console.log("has keyF in obj");
```

Comment: Or if no key1.. `if (!("key1" in obj)) { console.log("no key1 in obj"); }`

Answer (score 7):

Above answers are good. But this is good too and useful.

```
!obj['your_key']  // if 'your_key' not in obj the result --> true
```

It's good for short style of code special in if statements:

```
if (!obj['your_key']){
    // if 'your_key' not exist in obj
    console.log('key not in obj');
} else {
    // if 'your_key' exist in obj
    console.log('key exist in obj');
}
```

Note: If your key be equal to null or "" your "if" statement will be wrong.

```
obj = {'a': '', 'b': null, 'd': 'value'}
!obj['a']    // result ---> true
!obj['b']    // result ---> true
!obj['c']    // result ---> true
!obj['d']    // result ---> false
```

So, best way for checking if a key exists in a obj is:`'a' in obj`

Answer (score 3):

use the `hasOwnProperty()`,

```
if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

}
```

For Example :

```
const object1 = {
        one : 'value of one',
        two : 'value of two',
        three : 'value of three',
    };

console.log(object1.hasOwnProperty('one'));
// expected output: true

console.log(object1.hasOwnProperty('value of one'));
// expected output: false

console.log(object1.hasOwnProperty('four'));
// expected output: false
```

Answer (score 1):

`map.has(key)` is the latest *ECMAScript 2015* 
 way of checking the existance of a key in a map. [Refer to this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has) for complete details.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
const data = {
  name : "Test",
  value: 12
}

if("name" in data){
  //Found
}
else {
  //Not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is

```js
const obj = {
  a: 'value of a',
  b: 'value of b',
  c: 'value of c'
};

if(obj.a){
  console.log(obj.a);
}else{
  console.log('obj.a does not exist');
}
```

Comment: if `a` is either an empty string, zero or null, it will still return 'obj.a does not exist', even though the key `a` does exists.

Comment: in the case of boolean type, this will fail

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys(object).indexOf()` scenario:

1. With `Object.keys(object)` you create an array of keys.
2. Use `indexOf()` to find out if the key you're looking for is part of this array:

```
let testObject = {
a: 1,
b: 2
}

Object.keys(testObject).indexOf('a') > -1 // expect true - the key exists
Object.keys(testObject).indexOf('c') > -1 // expect false - the key didn't exists
```

Comment: You can edit the answer and add language style.

Answer (score -3):

This works for me like a charm. I'm inside a `foreach` function
this didn't work `obj.hasOwnProperty("key1")` also this `"key1" in obj`

```
let $schedule = {lesson:'asd',age:'sad'}
    
$schedules.forEach(function(e) {
    if (e['lesson']) {
        $title = e.lesson.lesson_name;
    } else {
        $title = 'No lesson Attached';
    }
});
```