# NodeJS: How to check if a key exists in an array of JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have an array of JSON objects `imdb` and I want to check if a key exists. I have tried couple different methods but none of them shows the correct result. I looked into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922965/check-if-object-key-exists-within-array) but doesn't help. Below code

```
var imdb = [{"123":"hi"}, {"234":"hello"}];  //array of JSON object
var valEventTime = 123;                      //key I want to find if exists


//approach 1
function getValueByKey(key, data) {
    var i, len = data.length;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (data[i] && data[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            return data[i][key];
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

if(getValueByKey(valEventTime, imdb) > -1){
  console.log("Yes");

}
else {
  console.log("NOT")
}


//approach 2
if (imdb[valEventTime]) {
    console.log("Yes");
} else {
    console.log("NOT")
}

//approach 3
var keys=Object.keys(imdb)
for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
     if(keys[i]==valEventTime)
     {//check your key here
       console.log("Yes")
     }
     else console.log("NOT")
}
```

The output always shows `NOT` even though I am searching for a key that already exists (`123`). Please suggest.

Comment: can you update json data in your question ?

Comment: @Chandru not sure what you meant? I already have the JSON data var imdb = [{"123":"hi"}, {"234":"hello"}];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that you are trying to search for a integer key where as your json key is a string.

> var imdb = [{"123":"hi"}, {"234":"hello"}];  // key is string
>
> var valEventTime = 123;  // key is integer

```js
var imdb = [{"123":"hi"}, {"234":"hello"}]; 
var valEventTime = "123";  

var obj = imdb.some((val) => {
 return Object.keys(val).includes(valEventTime);
})

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to determine if an array contains a value. For each item you want to use the [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function to check for your variable for the items return from [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) on each entry. In your example your variable is an integer and the key is a string - you may want to be more specific in your matching.

```
var imdb = [{"123":"hi"}, {"234":"hello"}];
var valEventTime = "123"; // use a string to match the keys

// use Array.some() to loop through each item and short circuit when we return true
var hasKey = imdb.some(function(movie) {
  // get the object keys as an array and see if that array contains your variable
  // returning true will also return true from Array.some()
  return Object.keys(movie).includes(valEventTime);
});
```