# Check if key exists in object **at any level**

Tags: javascript

What if I want to, with an object of arbitrary depth, see if a key occurs **anywhere** in it.
Take for example, this object:

```
let obj = {
  "heave": {
    "blah": 2,
    "foo": {
      "bar": "yes"
    }
  },
  "hoo": {
    "obj": "you were fooled",
    "number": {
      "ha": "ha"
    }
  }
};
```

and I want to find if it has the key `bar` on any level, preferably in one statement. I know I can just loop through every level, this is a "there's gotta be a better way" question.
I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922965/check-if-object-key-exists-within-array) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object), but they only answer the first level and neither question's answers work deeper.

Comment: Please edit the question title to indicate "object" rather than "array".