# A Better Way to Try / Check array length in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

What would be a better way to try checking that response is an array with length?

```
try{
    response.errors.length > 0;
    deferred.reject(response)
}
catch(e){
    deferred.resolve(response);
}
```

Comment: The length check will *not* throw an exception. What *might* is `response` or `response.errors` evaluating to undefined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if an associative array key exists in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-an-associative-array-key-exists-in-javascript)

Comment: To be clear, I want this expression to evaluate in the context of try catch so that I can capture the exception.  As per jshint: "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression." All the answers imply that I should not even be using try, which is fine. I'm just wondering how I would satisfy the jshint error.

Answer (score 2):

This will make sure that errors is an array and it has items in it.

```
if (Array.isArray(response.errors) && response.errors.length) {
    deferred.reject(response);
} else {
    deferred.resolve(response);
}
```

Comment: I dare say never check for if something is-an array; that's what duck typing is for ;-) The exception would be if I need to perform some kind of "overloading" based on a parameter - in which case the explicit check is more prudent.

Comment: @user2246674 Agreed. But this is what the OP want I believe. `checking that response is an array with length`

Comment: I suppose that is a reading - although not mine :) This answer is perfectly correct in the provided context.

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

```
if (response.errors.length) {
    deferred.reject(response);
} else {
    deferred.resolve(response);
}
```

This is using the fact that `0` is considered falsey in JavaScript, and any other number is considered truthy.

If you're worried about the type of `response.errors`, you can add `response.errors instanceof Array` to the `if` condition:

```
if (response.errors instanceof Array && response.errors.length) {
```

Comment: How do we make sure that it is an Array? Even functions can have length property.

Comment: @thefourtheye Good point, this is arguably in scope for this question, edited.

Comment: @thefourtheye We *don't* care if it's an array. Duck-typing.

Comment: @user2246674 Why don't we care? The question clearly asks specifically about arrays, there may be the need for it. No reason not to include that bit of knowledge.

Comment: @ajp15243 Because it's an orthogonal topic - the meat of the question is how to handle where there may be an *optional* array, not that there is an arbitrary value which *may be* an array.

Comment: @user2246674 True, I figured it was a tangential topic at best, hence my keeping it separate from the core answer.

Answer (score 0):

The length check (`length > x`) will *not* throw an exception. What *might* throw an exception is if `response` or `errors` evaluates to undefined (e.g. doesn't exist).

```
if (response && response.errors && response.errors.length) {
  // Have errors
  // The check for response might not be needed, but one should most
  // definitely ensure that `response.errors` evaluates to an object (Array?)
  // before trying to access a property upon it.
}
```

Note that this uses `&&` *short-circuiting* behavior.

Alternatively, sometimes it's nice to normalize data (assumes `response` is always an object). In this case we make sure that we have an "empty array" as needed such that we have some array on which to check the length.

```
response.errors = response.errors || []
if (response.errors.length) {
   // Have errors
}
```

In the above examples I also utilize that a non-0 number in JavaScript is a truth-y value, which allows `if (length > 0) ..` to be written as `if (length) ..` and it will work reliably assuming that length is always a number, when present.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
if (response.errors && response.errors.length > 0)
   deferred.reject(response);
else
    deferred.resolve(response);
```

No need to catch exceptions from accessing non-existent properties, just test for their existence before…

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be explicit about checking that it is an array.

```
if (response.errors && (response.errors instanceof Array) && response.errors.length > 0)
   deferred.reject(response);
else
   deferred.resolve(response);
```

(Tested in FF and Chrome).