# Search for data in json - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json output as

```
amt: "10.00"
email: "sam@gmail.com"
merchant_id: "sam"
mobileNo: "9874563210"
orderID: "123456"
passkey: "1234"
```

Literally Im trying to do *this* in javascript

```
if(the json output has the key merchant_id)
{
//do something
}
```

How is it possible to find if a json output has a key like as I demonstrated above?Is it possible,Or is there any alternate method for it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if an associative array key exists in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-an-associative-array-key-exists-in-javascript)

Comment: Is this a multiline string? Or is it a json object? What's the exact format and type of the variable you get your data in?

Comment: Yep, then it's the easy way, if(x.merchant_id=="whatYouWant")

Comment: hey no yaar.I want to search if 'merchant_id' exists,not its value.If(json has merchant_id){// }  like this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1098955/1636522, not the answer you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have JSON object like this:

```
var json = {
   amt: "10.00",
   email: "sam@gmail.com",
   merchant_id: "sam",
   mobileNo: "9874563210",
   orderID: "123456",
   passkey: "1234"
}
```

So now you have to use a loop. E.g.

```
for(var j in json) { // var j is the key in this loop
   if(j == 'merchant_id') {
      // do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the type of of the field.

```
if (typeof json.property !== 'undefined') {
    //has property
}
```

Comment: Can you specify this with my question,so it wil be more clear

Comment: If you have a JSON formatted like this: var json = {
   amt: "10.00",
   email: "sam@gmail.com",
   merchant_id: "sam",
   mobileNo: "9874563210",
   orderID: "123456",
   passkey: "1234"
} and you need to check the existance of the orderID field just do: if (typeof json.orderID!== 'undefined') {
    //has property
}

Answer (score 0):

If this is a multiline string like you wrote it, a simple way is:

```
if(s.indexOf("\nmerchant_id: \"whatever\"\n")>-1) {
    // ...
}
```

But you can parse it of course, and that's the elegant way.
With a json object, you can just refer to the field with a dot, like "obj.merchant_id".

Comment: Its a json object actually which is parsed

Comment: Easy pie then. Use the dot syntax mentioned above. (Also if you're hunting for the key only, not regarding its value, franchetto is right.)

Comment: so how it wil come,like this? I dont want to check the value of the key,but i want to search if this key exists in the object

Comment: But I didnt understand his answer any more,can you help?

Comment: Check franchetto's answer

Answer (score 0):

For example, try this:

```
var data = {
   amt: "10.00",
   email: "sam@gmail.com",
   merchant_id: "sam",
   mobileNo: "9874563210",
   orderID: "123456",
   passkey: "1234"
}

if(data.amt == 'something'){
   // do work
}
```