# Finding if an array node exists in json and concatenating it tostring

Tags: jquery

My sample data

```
var data = { "users":[
            {
                "firstName":"Ray",
                "lastName":"Villalobos",
                "joined": [""]

            },
            {
                "firstName":"John",
                "lastName":"Jones",
                "joined": ["Jan","15","2014"]

            }
    ]};
```

I would like to check if 'joined' node exists, check if it is empty (as in first users element) and if it has value then concatenate them.

Sincerely appreciate any help..

Thanks

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: "Concatenate" them how? Just the values in each one? All the values in all of them together?

Comment: `if (data["joined"] && data["joined"] !== '') {}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if an array key exists in a JavaScript object or array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-an-array-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object-or-array)

Comment: @Alex -Tx, so I should try if ("joined" in data.users)- that should give me whether joined node exists.. what do I do to figure if it has at least one string and not [""]

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I would like it concatenated with space seaparation eg. "Jan 15 2014"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply loop through, check that the `joined` property isn't falsey, and use `Array#join`.

```
data.users.forEach(function(user) {
    if (user.joined) {
        user.joined = user.joined.join(" ");
    }
});
```

`forEach` is one way of looping through arrays in JavaScript, it was added in ES5. [There are a bunch of other ways.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/how-to-do-for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476)

In the above, your first one will get converted from `[""]` to `""`; if that's not what you want, you add more checks:

```
data.users.forEach(function(user) {
    if (user.joined && (user.joined.length !== 1 || user.joined[0] !== "")) {
        user.joined = user.joined.join(" ");
    }
});
```