# Getting the difference between 2 JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have 2 JSON object arrays in my java script and i am trying to figure out a way to output the differences (if any) between the 2.

for example, here is one of the arrays :

```
   [{  
      "id":1,
      "colour":"BLACK",
      "size":"SML",
      "qty":1,
      "sml":"1"
   }]
```

and here is another :

```
        [{  
      "id":1,
      "colour":"BLACK",
      "size":"SML",
      "qty":1,
      "sml":"5",
      "lrg":"1"
       },
       {  
      "id":2,
      "colour":"BLACK",
      "size":"SML",
      "qty":1,
      "sml":"1"
       }]
```

In the above example i would print to the user that one product has been added, the id 1 product has had sml changed to 5 and lrg added. Is there a way to compare the 2 arrays and get the values that are changed / added?

Comment: please post the code you have tried

Comment: How do you know that a new item has been added? Are you comparing using `id` only?

Comment: I know somethings been added if the length of array 2 is larger than array 1

Answer (score 1):

There is a library for getting the structural differences between two objects
https://github.com/flitbit/diff

Comment: That looks like what i need, can it be used with angular?

Comment: Its NPM based so you can use it with Angular >= 2

Answer (score -1):

Affiliation: I am the author of this lib.

I would say
https://eggachecat.github.io/jycm-json-diff-viewer/
works perfectly for your task!

More interestingly, if 'qty' is something like a 'timestamp' which almost guarantees change, you can ignore this by simply doing a configuration.

Especially you can specify that you want to match the items by its id! with operator (rather than the overall similarity)

```json
{
  "operators": [
    {
      "name": "operator:list:matchWithField",
      "args": [
        "^\\[\\d+\\]$",
        "id"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "ignore_orders": [
  ]
}
```

[image]

Step by step:

1. install deps

```bash
yarn add jycm
```

2. use the lib

```js
const {
    YouchamaJsonDiffer,
    ListItemFieldMatchOperator,
    make_ignore_order_func
} = require('jycm');

const left = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "colour": "BLACK",
    "size": "SML",
    "qty": 1,
    "sml": "1"
  }
];

const right = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "colour": "BLACK",
    "size": "SML",
    "qty": 1,
    "sml": "5",
    "lrg": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "colour": "BLACK",
    "size": "SML",
    "qty": 1,
    "sml": "1"
  }
];
const ycm = new YouchamaJsonDiffer(left, right, {
  "operators": [
    {
      "name": "operator:list:matchWithField",
      "args": [
        "^\\[\\d+\\]$",
        "id"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "ignore_orders": [
  ]
});

const diffResult = ycm.get_diff(true);
console.log(diffResult);
```

You can get

```json
{
  "list:add": [
    {
      "left": "__NON_EXIST__",
      "right": {
        "name": "David",
        "address": "Boston",
        "phone": 434323434
      },
      "left_path": "",
      "right_path": "details->[1]"
    }
  ],
  "list:remove": [
    {
      "left": {
        "name": "Jam",
        "address": "Kentucky",
        "phone": 56034033343
      },
      "right": "__NON_EXIST__",
      "left_path": "details->[1]",
      "right_path": ""
    }
  ],
  "value_changes": [
    {
      "left": "1",
      "right": "2",
      "left_path": "id",
      "right_path": "id",
      "old": "1",
      "new": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Or here's a codesniffet:

```js
const {
  YouchamaJsonDiffer,
  ListItemFieldMatchOperator,
  make_ignore_order_func,
} = jycm;

const left = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "colour": "BLACK",
    "size": "SML",
    "qty": 1,
    "sml": "1"
  }
];

const right = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "colour": "BLACK",
    "size": "SML",
    "qty": 1,
    "sml": "5",
    "lrg": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "colour": "BLACK",
    "size": "SML",
    "qty": 1,
    "sml": "1"
  }
];
const ycm = new YouchamaJsonDiffer(left, right, {
  "operators": [
    {
      "name": "operator:list:matchWithField",
      "args": [
        "^\\[\\d+\\]$",
        "id"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "ignore_orders": [
  ]
});

const diffResult = ycm.get_diff(true);
console.log(diffResult);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jycm@0.2.0/dist/index.js"></script>
```