# In React Native, how can I console.log() every time state is set?

Tags: react-native

Preferably 1 line code in the constructor.
I don't want to console.log() on every callback of `setState`

Is there some listener for changes?

Comment: You could insert a `console.log()` inside the `render` before the `return`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle function to show the state change:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   console.log(prevState, this.state);
  }
```

For detecting the actual change use [deep object comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683075/how-to-do-a-deep-comparison-between-2-objects-with-lodash).

Working 
  [Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/qzvy85lj24?expanddevtools=1)
.