# (Lodash) Is there a method to check if an identical object exists (nested) in a collection?

Tags: javascript, match, lodash

I was wondering if there is a Lodash approach to this problem, which I would otherwise solve with a `for` loop. I would like to return `true` if `collection` contains one or more elements with nested object identical to `c`.

The below example would return `true` because `collection[1]` contains an identical `c`.

Needle:

```
c = {
  x: 11,
  y: 22,
  z: 33
}
```

Haystack:

```
collection = [
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: {
      x: 10,
      y: 20,
      z: 30
    },
    d: 1
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: {
      x: 11,
      y: 22,
      z: 33
    },
    d: 1
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: {
      x: 12,
      y: 24,
      z: 36
    },
    d: 1
  }
]
```

This is different from questions such as [How to do a deep comparison between 2 objects with lodash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683075/how-to-do-a-deep-comparison-between-2-objects-with-lodash) because I need to check if any of the collection items contain an identical object nested within them, not compare whether two objects are identical to each other.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a deep comparison between 2 objects with lodash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683075/how-to-do-a-deep-comparison-between-2-objects-with-lodash)

Comment: Not really the same question, but `for` loop with `_.isEqual` is one way to go, unless there is a method that I have overlooked that does the iteration and comparison in one.

Comment: That's not a single method, but you could use`_.uniq` and then compare original size and new size, and if they are different, it had duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`_.isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEqual) in a recursive function:

```js
function find(h, n) {
  if (_.isEqual(h, n)) return true;

  let found;
  if (Array.isArray(h)) {
    for (let e of h) {
      found = find(e, n);
      if (found) return found;
    }
  } else if (h instanceof Object) {
    return find(Object.values(h), n);
  }
  
  return false;
}


var c = {
  x: 11,
  y: 22,
  z: 33
};

var d = {
  x: 1111,
  y: 2222,
  z: 32223
};


var collection = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: {
      x: 10,
      y: 20,
      z: 30
    },
    d: 1
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: {
      x: 11,
      y: 22,
      z: 33
    },
    d: 1
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: {
      x: 12,
      y: 24,
      z: 36
    },
    d: 1
  }
];

console.log(find(collection, c));
console.log(find(collection, d));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is nice and concise. Thank you.