# How to get FormControlName of the field which value changed in Angular reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a reactive form with over 10 form controls and using subscription on valueChanges observable to detect changes. It works perfectly but output is always the entire form value object(meaning all the form controls and their values). Is there a way to simply get the form control name of the field that changed?

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    field1: ['', Validators.required],
    field2: ['', Validators.required],
    field3: ['', Validators.required],
    field4: ['', Validators.required],
    field5: ['', Validators.required],
    field6: ['', Validators.required],
    field7: ['', Validators.required],
    field8: ['', Validators.required],
    field9: ['', Validators.required],
    field10: ['', Validators.required],
    field11: ['', Validators.required],
    field12: ['', Validators.required],
    field13: [{ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required]
});

this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(
    result => this.calculateParams(result)
);

calculateParams(result) {
    console.log(result); // giving the entire form.value object
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a work-around but if store the old values you can do some like

```
this.old={...this.myForm.value}
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
  const key=Object.keys(res).find(k=>res[k]!=this.old[k])
  this.old={...this.myForm.value}
})
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick. I originally though of something similar but hoped that there's maybe a "slicker" solution.. Thanks!

Comment: In Angular 6 and Angular 7, there was a different between myform.get('...').value and "res", or between res and myform.value[...], (even I think remember that you could subscribe to (res,old)=>{..}) but in Angular 8 looks like there's no diference. Really I don't know if ther'e a better solution

Answer (score 5):

The rxjs way of Eliseo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56731443/7912744)

```
this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(this.form.value),
    pairwise(),
    map(([oldValues, newValues]) => {
        return Object.keys(newValues).find(k => newValues[k] != oldValues[k]);
    }),
).subscribe(key => {
    console.log( key )
});
```

Comment: This seems like a nice solution. However, the first time this is triggered, despite the `startWith`, it will always return the first control of the form for me, regardless of which one actually had the change. Second time onwards, it works fine. I'm confused because even the first time, if I compare oldValues and newValues, the only difference is in the control that actually changed its value.

Answer (score 1):

You can isolate the formcontrol from the formgroup by using the `get` method and the access the `valueChanges` method on it.

`this.form.get('formcontrolName').valueChanges()`.

Note: `form.get` returns you the `AbstractControl`, which also has the `valueChanges` method on it.

Comment: right, but then in order to subscribe to all values I would have to subscribe to each of them separately(for each form control) and I want to avoid that because I'll have forms with a lot more fields than this.

Comment: you can extract out the config for `fb.group` so that you can use `Object.keys` on it and subscribe to each field in a forEach loop

Comment: @dimitri Can you try this `this.form.valueChanges().pipe(map(form => form.controls), filter(control => control.dirty)).subscribe()`;

Comment: @PhuNgo wouldn't that many subscriptions(e.g. 50+) on a single component at some point be a memory bottleneck?

Comment: @KiraAG - not getting any results(`Cannot read property 'dirty' of undefined`). What's the chain of thoughts here?

Comment: The idea is to get the form controls and filter them using the property `dirty`, which filters out the controls whose values has been changed in the UI.

Comment: Ok Sorry, I misread `form.controls` returns array, it actually return you an object. Can you try this `this.form.valueChanges().pipe(map(form => Object.values(form.controls)), filter(control => control.dirty)).subscribe()`. Now you will get an array of `form controls`.

Comment: @dimitri subscribe to each field in the forEach loop, not to the whole group. But you made a good point with the bottleneck issue

Comment: @KiraAG - but wouldn't that just return all "dirty" values, meaning all the fields that have been "touched"? What if I decide to switch back between fields and continue changing them?

Comment: Isn’t that what you wanted?

Comment: @KiraAG sorry if question was not clear, but no - just a single field which value was updated last

Comment: Oh , I think this is a bit complex requirement, for which may you need pairwise operator.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't fully tested the code but the idea is to pair the controls and their key then listen to `valueChanges` on each control simultaneously and return object key instead of value (and of course you can map both value and key to the output)

```
const fields={
    field1: ['', Validators.required],
    field2: ['', Validators.required],
    field3: ['', Validators.required],
    field4: ['', Validators.required],
    field5: ['', Validators.required],
    field6: ['', Validators.required],
}

zip(
 from(Object.values(fb.group(fields).controls)),
 from(Object.keys(fields))
).pipe(mergeMap([control,key])=>control.valueChanges.pipe(mapTo(key)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to each change individually.

```
for (const controlProperty in this.myForm.controls) {
    if (this.myForm.controls.hasOwnProperty(controlProperty)) {
      this.myForm.controls[controlProperty].valueChanges.pipe(untilDestroyed(this)).subscribe(result => {
        console.log(controlProperty + " is now ", result);
      });
    }
}
```

This just felt more angular-y to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `valueChanges` for each control after adding control dynamically to `FormGroup`.

```
const ct = {key: 'myControl'};    
this.myForm.addControl(ct.key, new FormControl('', Validators.required))
this.myForm.controls[ct.key].valueChanges
.subscribe(d => {
    // here ct will be available as closure , so that we can access every form control here and do operation accordingly
    console.log(d, ct.key);
})
```

Here `ct` object will be available inside subscribe as a closure.

Comment: Terribly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

The method from @alex-walker (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64830665/134120) seems to be the best, but it only works well on flat forms, with simple key-value pairs. If you have nested forms, with FormArrays of FormGroups, the `key` property in that method will only return the top-level key of the form, which is not very useful if you want e.g. to indicate to the user the particular input field that triggered the event.

So I combined this method with a deep object diff method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50278133/134120

To get something like this:

```
this.form.valueChanges
    .pipe(
        startWith(this.form.value),
        pairwise(),
        map(([oldValues, newValues]) => {
            return bdiff(oldValues, newValues);
        })
    )
    .subscribe(keys => {
        console.log(keys);
    });

bdiff(a: Record<string, any>, b: Record<string, any>): string[] {
    return _reduce(
        a,
        (res, val, key) =>
            res.concat(
                (_isPlainObject(val) || Array.isArray(val)) && b
                    ? this.bdiff(val, b[key]).map(x => key + (key.trim ? '' : ']') + (x.search(/^\d/) ? '.' : '[') + x)
                    : !b || val !== b[key]
                    ? [key + (key.trim ? '' : ']')]
                    : []
            ),
        []
    );
}
```

Which will return an array of nested keys such as `keys = ['fieldgroup2.fieldArray[3].myNestedField']` which you should easily access and set as invalid with `form.get(keys[0]).valid`.