# compare JS objects with values null and empty string

Tags: javascript, lodash

How can I compare these below two JavaScript objects to be equal and true

```js
var obj1 = {
  'a': 'something',
  'b': null
};
var obj2 = {
  'a': 'something',
  'b': ''
}

var isTrue = _.isEqual(obj1, obj2);

alert(isTrue);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a deep comparison between 2 objects with lodash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683075/how-to-do-a-deep-comparison-between-2-objects-with-lodash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, they are not equals. `'' !== null`. 
What you could do, is change every empty value to be null first, an then compare them.

```js
var obj1 = {
  'a': 'something',
  'b': null
};
var obj2 = {
  'a': 'something',
  'b': ''
}



var isTrue = _.isEqual(mapEmptyValueToNull(obj1), mapEmptyValueToNull(obj2));
console.log(isTrue);

// we change every value of '' to null.
function mapEmptyValueToNull(object) {
  Object.keys(object).forEach((key) => {
    if(object[key] === '') {
      object[key] = null;
    }
  });
  return object;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`_.isEqualWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqualWith) and create a custom predicate to handle this case:

```js
var obj1 = {
  'a': 'something',
  'b': null
};
var obj2 = {
  'a': 'something',
  'b': ''
}

var isTrue = _.isEqualWith(obj1, obj2, (a, b) => {
  // if both are null or equal to an empty string then they are equal
  if((_.isNull(a) || a === '') && (_.isNull(b) || b === '')) return true;
});

console.log(isTrue);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you.