# Check if all arrays in an object are equal to all arrays in another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

So I have a data structure like this:

```
formSubmissions: [
    {
        ids: [1,2,3,4,5],
        genders: ["male", "female"],
        times: ["1day","3days"]
    },
    ...
]
```

Basically, every time a form is submitted, I want to check if the object created from the three fields in the form, is equal to anything in the formSubmissions array. If not, I want to append it to the array.

What is the fastest way to accomplish this? I have tried some other stack overflow solutions to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Nodejs and all you need is to compare objects by their contents, `util.isDeepStrictEqual()` can be useful:

```js
if (!this.formData.some(elem => util.isDeepStrictEqual(elem, submitted))) {
    this.formData.push(submitted);
}
```

But please note that array values in different objects will not match if their ordering is different.

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I came up with while waiting for a response:

```
if (!(this.formData.some(el => el.voIds === submitted.voIds && 
                               el.genderList === submitted.genderList && 
                               el.times === submitted.times))) {
        this.formData.push(submitted);
      }
```

It seems to work. Any suggestions on how it can be improved?

Comment: Even if it works, it looks difficult to maintain in case the structure of your objects evolve, that's why I would advise using a function for this

Comment: You're totally right. If i expect it to change, I will move to your solution. At the current time though, I don't think it will ever change.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using Lodash [_.isEqual()](https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual) as per the accepted answer in
[How to do a deep comparison between 2 objects with lodash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683075/how-to-do-a-deep-comparison-between-2-objects-with-lodash)

```js
if (!this.formData.some(elem => _.isEqual(elem, submitted))) {
    this.formData.push(submitted);
}
```

Note that as other Lodash utilities, it is available as a standalone NPM package, so you do not have to depend on the rest of the library.