# Lodash Difference between two objects

Tags: javascript, lodash, javascript-objects

I am comparing two objects with the help of Lodash `isEqual` function and trying to get difference with `difference` function.

The `difference` function is returning whole object instead of only those attributes which are different.

Is there any way to find only mismatched attributes in objects?

Comment: [`_.difference()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#difference) is supposed to be used with arrays.

Comment: Relevant: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) and [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a deep comparison between 2 objects with lodash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683075/how-to-do-a-deep-comparison-between-2-objects-with-lodash)

Answer (score 19):

```js
const obj1 = {
  a: "old value",
  b: {
    c: "old value"
  },
  d: 123
}
const obj2 = {
  a: "old value",
  b: {
    c: "new value"
  },
  d: 321
}
const changes =
  _.differenceWith(_.toPairs(obj2), _.toPairs(obj1), _.isEqual)

// Changes in array form
console.log(changes)
// Changes in object form
console.log(_.fromPairs(changes))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cool, it detects changes even if fields order is different! But it's not recursive: if add `, c2: "old value"` to both `b` fields, then `c2` will leak to diff too even if it was not changed.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the comparison between two objects but in my case, I wanted to check only some properties of the objects. So I use pick and isEqual from lodash.

```
const obj1 = {p1: 1, p2: 2, p3: 3};
const obj2 = {p1: 1, p2: 2, p3: 3};

const comparisonProperties = ["p1", "p2"];

console.log(_.isEqual(_.pick(obj1, comparisonProperties), _.pick(obj2, comparisonProperties))
```

This is how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily compare two objects without lodash

```js
const obj1 = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 4,
  four: 3,
};

const obj2 = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3,
  four: 4,
};

const diffInVariantFields = (obj1, obj2) => {
  const diffInFields = Object.entries(obj2).filter(
    ([field, obj2Value]) => obj1[field] !== obj2Value
  );
  return diffInFields;
};

console.log(diffInVariantFields(obj1, obj2)); // [ [ 'three', 3 ], [ 'four', 4 ] ]
```