# How to check equality of two objects, one object's attribute's type is number other ones type is string but they are numbers

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

How to check equality of two objects which is one object type is number other one comes as a string type but a number

```
var object1 = {  
        x1: "1.000000",
        x2: undefined,
        x3: "1.0",
        x4: "1.0" 
};
var object2 = {  
        x1: 1,
        x2: undefined,
        x2: 1,
        x4: 1 
};
```

lodash returns false for above scenario.
_.isEqual(object1, object2);

Comment: Map over keys (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Tangentially related: [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201183/11407695)

Comment: Also related: [How to do a deep comparison between 2 objects with lodash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31683075/11407695)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`_.isEqualWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqualWith):

```js
var object1 = {  
        x1: "1.000000",
        x2: undefined,
        x3: "1.0",
        x4: "1.0" 
};
var object2 = {  
        x1: 1,
        x2: undefined,
        x3: 1,
        x4: 1 
};

const cmpStr2Num = (val1, val2) => {
  if ((typeof val1 === 'string' && typeof val2 === 'number')
   || (typeof val2 === 'string' && typeof val1 === 'number'))
     return Number(val1) === Number(val2)
}

console.log(_.isEqualWith(object1, object2, cmpStr2Num))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var object1 = {
  x1: "1.000000",
  x2: undefined,
  x3: "1.0",
  x4: "1.0"
};
var object2 = {
  x1: 1,
  x2: undefined,
  x2: 1,
  x4: 1
};

const equal = !Object.keys(object1).some(key => object1[key] != object2[key])

console.log(equal)
```

However, in your example, `object2` has a key overwritten (`x2` is defined twice), so the objects using the code above are not considered equal

Comment: Why the lodash import?

Comment: @Ricola not sure if I understand your question

Comment: You start your snipped with `import _ from 'lodash'` but don't use it

Comment: ah, true :+1: thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because string and number are different types.

```
"1" === 1 // false
```

Can coerce types of object's values

```
const coerceObject = object => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) => {
        return [[key], Number.isNaN(+value) ? value : Number.parseFloat(value)]
    })
)

   _.isEqual(coerceObject(object1), coerceObject(object2));
```