# How to check equality of two objects(only specific key values)

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

How to check equality of two objects(only specific key values) which is one object type is number other one comes as a string type, but they are numbers.
I want to check equality of x1, x2, x3 and x4 value of the two objects not all of the object values

```
var object1 = {
        id: 1234
        x1: "1.000000",
        x2: undefined,
        x3: "1.0",
        x4: "1.0",
        x5: somevale 1
};
var object2 = {
        id: 3456
        x1: 1,
        x2: undefined,
        x3: 1,
        x4: 1,
        x5: somevalue 2
};
```

I received the answer from [How to check equality of two objects, one object's attribute's type is number other ones type is string but they are numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68334868/how-to-check-equality-of-two-objects-one-objects-attributes-type-is-number-ot)
This solution checks every attributes of the object which I get false for my two objects, because other attributes can not be same.

Answer (score 0):

You can just compare if the two objects have the same keys using `Object.keys`.

```js
function keysEqual(obj1, obj2){
    const keys1 = Object.keys(obj1), keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);
    return keys1.length === keys2.length && keys1.every(key => keys2.includes(key))
}
var object1 = {
        id: 1234,
        x1: "1.000000",
        x2: undefined,
        x3: "1.0",
        x4: "1.0",
        x5:  1
};
var object2 = {
        id: 3456,
        x1: 1,
        x2: undefined,
        x3: 1,
        x4: 1,
        x5:  2
};
console.log(keysEqual(object1, object2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of the [accepted answer of your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68334988/14426823) - The two objects are only consider equal if fields "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4" are loosely equal - other fields are left out of the comparison step

The gist of the algorithm is to use Js `every` function: For every field in ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"], `object1` must (loosely) equal `object2` at that field

```js
const fieldsToCheck = ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"];

function equal(obj1, obj2, fieldsToCheckFor = fieldsToCheck) {
  return fieldsToCheckFor.every((key) => obj1[key] == obj2[key]);
}

var object1 = {
  id: 1234,
  x1: "1.000000",
  x2: undefined,
  x3: "1.0",
  x4: "1.0",
};
var object2 = {
  id: 3456,
  x1: 1,
  x2: undefined,
  x3: 1,
  x4: 1,
};

var object3 = {
  id: 3456,
  x1: 1,
  x2: undefined,
  x3: 1,
  x4: 1,
  x5: 7,
  randomFieldThatDoesNotGetChecked: "a72",
};

var object4 = {
  id: 3456,
  x1: 1,
  x2: "x2 has been defined",
  x3: 1,
  x4: 1,
  x5: 7,
  randomFieldThatDoesNotGetChecked: "a72",
};

// Should be True
console.log("Test1", equal(object1, object2));

// Should be True
console.log("Test2", equal(object2, object3));

// Should be False
console.log("Test3", equal(object1, object4));
```

Comment: Object 1's  x1, x2, x3 and x4 values are string type but they are numbers
Object 2's  x1, x2, x3 and x4 values are number type 

I want to check equality of object 1's(x1, x2, x3 and x4) against Object 2's x1, x2, x3 and x4

 whether Object 1(x1, x2, x3 and x4) === Object 2 (x1, x2, x3 and x4)

Comment: I think that's exactly what I did (or tried to do). Did anything not work for you in the code above ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var object1 = {
        id: 1234,
        x1: "1.000000",
        x2: undefined,
        x3: "1.0",
        x4: "1.0",
        x5: 1
};
var object2 = {
        id: 3456,
        x1: 1,
        x2: undefined,
        x3: 1,
        x4: 1,
        x5: 2
};

var check = ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"];

console.log(eval());

function eval() {
  for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
    if (object1[check[i]] != object2[check[i]]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each key using `array#every` and check if key exists in both object and then compare their values.

```js
const object1 = { id: 1234, x1: "1.000000", x2: undefined, x3: "1.0", x4: "1.0", x5: 'somevale 1' },
      object2 = { id: 3456, x1: 1, x2: undefined, x3: 1, x4: 1, x5: 'somevalue 2' },
      keys = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'],
      result = keys.every(key => key in object1 && key in object2 && object1[key] == object2[key]);
console.log(result);
```