# How to check equality of two objects with selected attributes but they are different types

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have 2 point objects as below,
Please note that

1. point1 (p1, p2, p3 and p4) are string type but they are decimal point numbers.
2. point2 (p1, p2, p3 and p4) are numbers.
3. There are other properties in the objects as well but I don't need to compare equality of them
4. How can I compare equality for point1 (p1, p2, p3 and p4) === point2 (p1, p2, p3 and p4) only

   ```
   const point1 = {
     id: 1234,
     p1: "1.000000",
     p2: undefined,
     p3: "1.0",
     p4: "1.0",
     p5: "somevale 1"
   };

   const point2 = {
     id: 3456,
     p1: 1,
     p2: undefined,
     p3: 1,
     p4: 1,
     p5: "somevalue 2"
   };
   ```

Comment: Use `lodash` library, that provides lot of general purpose methods.
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual

Comment: `_.isEqual(object, other)` method of lodash.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68338945/how-to-check-equality-of-two-objectsonly-specific-key-values/68339117#68339117

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an array of `keys` that you want to check the equality for, then use `.every()` on that array to iterate over each key. For each key, you can check if its value from `point1` is numeric using isNaN(), and if it is, convert it to a number using the unary plus operator (`+`), otherwise, you can leave it as it's original value and compare this against the value at the key stored in `point2`. The callback to `.every()` needs to return `true` for all keys in your array for `pointsEqual` to be `true`, otherwise it will be `false` if there is a mismatch between two keys:

```js
const point1 = { id: 1234, p1: "1.000000", p2: undefined, p3: "1.0", p4: "1.0", p5: "somevale 1" };
const point2 = { id: 3456, p1: 1, p2: undefined, p3: 1, p4: 1, p5: "somevalue 2" };

const keys = ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"];
const pointsEqual = keys.every(
  key => (isNaN(point1[key]) ? point1[key] : +point1[key]) === point2[key]
);
console.log(pointsEqual); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Javascript, you need to [loop through items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript) and compare individually. Also, === is for type check. Use == to skip type check.

Comment: I am using typescript

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop to loop from 1 to 4 and get the corresponding property by concatenating `"p"` to the index like so:

```js
const point1 = {
  id: 1234,
  p1: "1.000000",
  p2: undefined,
  p3: "1.0",
  p4: "1.0",
  p5: "somevale 1"
};
const point2 = {
  id: 3456,
  p1: 1,
  p2: undefined,
  p3: 1,
  p4: 1,
  p5: "somevalue 2"
};
var isEqual = true;
for(let i = 1; i < 5; i++){
  if(point1["p"+i] !== point2["p"+i]){
    isEqual = false;
  }
}
console.log(isEqual);
```

Note the difference between `!=` and `!==`. (one compares types, the other does not)

Comment: p1, p2, p3 p4 are just for filed name to explain the question here but actually they have unique names which doesn't have a pattern