# Lodash 4: How to compare two object keys and return differences?

Tags: lodash

I have two objects like so:

`originalObj`:

```
{
    name: "Jane",
    fullName: "Jane Doe"
    nickname: "Janey"
    ...etc...
}
```

`updatedObj`:

```
{
    name: "Jane",
    fullName: "Jane Dawn", //<--this value changed
    nickname: "Janey"
    ...etc..
}
```

**With lodash 4, how can I compare both objects and just return the updated values with key?**

So, for example, I would expect to see:

```
{
    fullName: "Jane Dawn",
        ...etc...
}
```

My use case is that I want to show a "before" and "after" view to a user of existing database data and user-updated form data before submitting to a server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39813128/4758494

Comment: that returned an object without the updated keys/values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's flat object, ie no nested objects or arrays, you can use `_.pickBy()` on the updated object, and take every property that is not equal to the similar property from the original object:

```js
const originalObj = {"name":"Jane","fullName":"Jane Doe","nickname":"Janey"}
const updatedObj = {"name":"Jane","fullName":"Jane Dawn","nickname":"Janey"}

const result = _.pickBy(updatedObj, (v, k) => !_.isEqual(originalObj[k], v))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

If you need to compare nested objects, use a package, such as [deep-object-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-object-diff)
.