# How to remove object if object matches

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove object if object matches, I dont want to compare any object key, I just want to compare whole object with array of object, and if it matches, then I have to remove that object from original array.

```
let originalArray = [
                {name: 'abc', country: 'eng'},
                {name: 'xyz', country: 'ind'},
                {name: 'pqr', country: 'us'}
            ]

    let objectToBeRemove = [
                {name: 'pqr', country: 'us'}
            ]

console.log(originalArray);
```

> Expected output:

```
 [
                    {name: 'abc', country: 'eng'},
                    {name: 'xyz', country: 'ind'}
]
```

I am not able to figure out how can I compare object, I can do it by id or any key, but I am making generic thing, so may be in few cases ID is not present, that's why I want to compare object

Comment: @Nitheesh I have array of object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the difference between two arrays of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987909/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: @slashroot no, I know the difference between those array, I just want to remove that different object from the original array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) + [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for comparison.

Note that `Array#filter` returns a new array. So the variable needs to be reassigned.

```js
let originalArray = [
  {name: 'abc', country: 'eng'},
  {name: 'xyz', country: 'ind'},
  {name: 'pqr', country: 'us'}
];

let objectToBeRemove = [
  {name: 'pqr', country: 'us'}
];

originalArray = originalArray.filter(obj => 
  objectToBeRemove.some(objToRemove => 
    JSON.stringify(objToRemove) !== JSON.stringify(obj)
  )
);

console.log(originalArray);
```

Note: Using `JSON.stringify()` is a little primitive for object comparison in my opinion. For instance the check would fail if the properties are in different order `{country: 'us', name: 'pqr'}`. Better way would be to do a deep comparison. For eg. using `_.isEqual` from `loadash` library. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31683111/6513921) for more info.

**Using `loadash`**

```js
let originalArray = [
  {name: 'abc', country: 'eng'},
  {name: 'xyz', country: 'ind'},
  {name: 'pqr', country: 'us'}
];

let objectToBeRemove = [
  {country: 'us', name: 'pqr'}
];

originalArray = originalArray.filter(obj => 
  objectToBeRemove.some(objToRemove => 
    !_.isEqual(objToRemove, obj)
  )
);

console.log(originalArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "filter" function to do that: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
var myArr = [{name: "toto"}, {name: "tata"}, {name: "tutu"}];
var toRemove = {name: "tata"};

let ret = myArr.filter(function(el) {
  return el.name != toRemove.name;
});
```

Or for removing multiple items:

```
var myArr = [{name: "toto"}, {name: "tata"}, {name: "tutu"}];
var toRemove = [{name: "tata"}, {name: "tutu"}];

for (var i = 0; i < toRemove.length; i++) {
  let index = myArr.findIndex((el) => { // Search item index to remove
    return el.name == toRemove[i].name;
  }); 

  if (index != -1) myArr.splice(index, 1); // Remove item in found index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare the equality of the complete object you could use the `JSON.stringify()` method.

Example;

```
JSON.stringfy(originalArray[i]) === JSON.stringfy(objectToBeRemove)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
let originalArray = [
      { name: 'abc', country: 'eng' },
      { name: 'xyz', country: 'ind' },
      { name: 'pqr', country: 'us' }
    ];
    let objectToBeRemove = [
      { name: 'pqr', country: 'us' }
    ];
    var finalResult = originalArray.filter(function(objFromA) {
      return !objectToBeRemove.find(function(objFromB) {
        return objFromA.name === objFromB.name
      })
    });
    console.log('???',finalResult);
```

Comment: OP states _"compare whole object"_. At the moment the answer only compares `name` property.