# Listen for changes in a Firestore collection

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

Firestore has a specific documentation for listening documents changes, like add, modify or remove (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).

For example, I can use an export function like the following to listen for a new document.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('my-collection/{docId}')
  .onCreate((change, context) => { /* ... */ });
```

Currently I'm building a Cloud Function that inserts multiple documents by means of a batch writing mechanism like the following.

```
const colRef = firestore.collection(collectionName)
const batch = firestore.batch();

items.forEach(item => {
    let docId = hashCode(item.title);
    let docRef = colRef.doc(`${docId}`);
    batch.set(docRef, {
        index: `${item.index}`,
        description: `${item.description}`,
        title: `${item.title}`
    });
});
return await batch.commit();
```

What I would like to achieve is the following: when I insert multiple documents into a collection, I need to send a push notification to my mobile client in order to let users know that new documents are available.

`onCreate`, `onUpdate`, `onDelete` or `onWrite` operate on a single document change and not in the entire collection.

Is there a way to listen when into a collection are added a bunch of elements?

Thanks,
Lorenzo

Comment: Can you please explain _"any mechanism to listen for changes in the collection."_ ? The `onCreate()` trigger can run a function whenever a document is added. If you are adding multiple documents then it'll trigger multiple functions.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I've added more details. Thanks.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I would like to listen for batch commit and not for every document that is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Firestore events trigger on document changes and each new document will trigger a Cloud Function. Instead you can use a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) that adds runs batched write and also send the notification. For example:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const { docs } = data;
  // TODO:
  // 1. Run Batched Write
  // 2. Send notification to user
});
```

This will invoke only 1 Cloud Function for all documents instead of a function for each document.

Comment: Is there any way to understand how many documents are committed with a batch insert? The code that I've shared do not prevent duplicates.

Comment: @LorenzoB You would have to check that in code itself if same object is being added again. [lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683075/how-to-do-a-deep-comparison-between-2-objects-with-lodash) might be useful. All the documents added by `batch.set()` will be added (since the doc ID is different for all) so count is essentially length of `items` arrays.

Comment: As you can see I'm using this function through which ids are set manually. `let docId = hashCode(item.title);`

Comment: @LorenzoB yes, but does that function return same ID every time for a given function? If not, then it'll create duplicates even if rest of the data is same. That's why you'll have to implement your own logic to filter duplicates from the array beforehand.

Comment: The function returns the same id performing an hash of the string in input.

Comment: Are you able to share some documentation in order to perform the logic for checking for duplicates and adding a document if it does not exist? I'm reading about [Transactions and batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) but I'm not sure if this are suitable for a Cloud Function. The documentation says about _Using the Cloud Firestore client libraries, you can group multiple operations into a single transaction_. In other words they are for client and not for server. Am I wrong?

Comment: @LorenzoB in that case can you please share a screenshot of what you mean by duplicates? If the doc ID is same for a title every time then it should not create multiple docs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The doc ID is the same but since I need to calculate how many documents are new (the ones that will be inserted) I need a way to read the doc ID first and check for its existence. SO, I'm wondering if Transactions are the best fit for that (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74155271/using-transactions-and-batched-writes-within-a-cloud-function).

Comment: Example given: suppose in the database I have 3 elements (which doc IDs are A, B, C). Now I need to insert 3 more elements (which doc IDs are C, D, E). The Cloud Function should add just the latest ones and send a Push Notification to the user telling him that 2 new documents are available. Hope it's clear.