# How to check if two objects with same structure are equals with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I would like to compare two objects:
I try to use this function:

```
export const isArrayEqual = (x, y) => {
  console.log('x',x);
  return _(x).xorWith(y, _.isEqual).isEmpty();
};
```

But i think that is not enought deep to check all the properties of the object.
How can i do it, deepless and check all the properties with the same function?

obj1:

```
{
        "list": {
            "text_list": "RESPUESTA CON LSITA 2",
            "items_list": [
                {
                    "value": "Valor 2",
                    "synonyms": [],
                    "idResponse": "CA2_1_E_2",
                    "title_item": "RESPUESTA 2"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Valor 3",
                    "synonyms": [],
                    "idResponse": "CA2_1_E_3",
                    "title_item": "Respuesta 3"
                }
            ],
            "title_list": "Titulo en EDICION"
        },
        "lateral": {},
        "finalResponse": {}
    }
```

obj2:

```
{
        "list": {
            "text_list": "RESPUESTA Editada",
            "items_list": [
                {
                    "value": "Valor 2",
                    "synonyms": [],
                    "idResponse": "CA2_1_E_2",
                    "title_item": "RESPUESTA 2"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Valor 3",
                    "synonyms": [],
                    "idResponse": "CA2_1_E_3",
                    "title_item": "Respuesta 5"
                }
            ],
            "title_list": "Titulo en EDICION"
        },
        "lateral": {},
        "finalResponse": {}
    }
```

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683075/how-to-do-a-deep-comparison-between-2-objects-with-lodash) it does a deep comparison. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve?

As for isEqual() function, you can see it works perfectly in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-matan-qksuqf?file=/src/index.js

If you're trying to compare two arrays this function should do the trick by itself.

Comment: I don't know why, i will try again.

Comment: @Barmar my first option isArrayEqual = (x, y), not works, the solution from _danielperaza is better. I don't know why. https://codesandbox.io/s/isequal-vs-worth-f95lrr?file=/src/index.js here both options.

Comment: When `.xorWith().isEmpty()` returns `true`, it means the objects are equal. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Lodash's `isEqual()` function should suffice as shown in this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-matan-qksuqf?file=/src/index.js.

If you're still not satisfied with this, you can implement your own function using recursion.