# How to check if a key exists in javascript array?

Tags: javascript

How can i check if a particular key exists in a JavaScript array?

Actually, i am checking for undefinedness for whether a key exists. What if the key exists but the value is actually undefined?

var obj = { key: undefined };
obj["key"] != undefined // false, but the key exists!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a key exists in a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 19):

With [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator.

```
0 in [10, 42] // true
2 in [10, 42] // false

'a' in { a: 'foo' } // true
'b' in { a: 'foo' } // false
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [the `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

```
if ( "my property name" in myObject )
```

Answer (score 4):

```
let $arr = [1, 0, false];

console.log($arr.indexOf(0));     // 1
console.log($arr.indexOf(false)); // 2
console.log($arr.indexOf(15));    // -1

if ($arr.indexOf(18) !== -1) //Todo
```

Comment: good answer, next time add some text to explain.

Answer (score 2):

### Array filter() function

You can use the Javascript array filter funtion. Like that:

```js
const arr = ["ab","cd"]
const needle = "cd"
console.log( arr.filter(i => i == needle).length > 0 ? "exists" : "not exists" )
```

Answer (score -1):

Use hasOwnProperty(key)

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let a = obj[i].hasOwnProperty(`${key}`);
        if(a){
            console.log(obj[i])
       }
    }
```