# Raw javascript in ng-if doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, indexing, key

I'm trying to check if a key exists in an object in an Angular $scope. In my controller I've got this:

```
$scope.the_object = {'the_key': 123};
```

And in my template I've got this:

```
<span ng-if="'the_key' in the_object">
    the_key exists in the_object
</span>
```

but I get the following trace in the console:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$parse/syntax?p0=in&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=11&p3='the_key'NaNn%20the_object&p4=in%20the_object
    at Error (native)
    at http://52.29.xx.xx:5000/bower/angular/angular.min.js?version=1.4.7:6:416
    at Object.s.throwError (http://52.29.xx.xx:5000/bower/angular/angular.min.js?version=1.4.7:209:339)
    at Object.s.ast (http://52.29.xx.xx:5000/bower/angular/angular.min.js?version=1.4.7:202:118)
    at Object.sd.compile (http://52.29.xx.xx:5000/bower/angular/angular.min.js?version=1.4.7:211:203)
    at fc.parse (http://52.29.xx.xx:5000/bower/angular/angular.min.js?version=1.4.7:238:193)
    at b.$get (http://52.29.xx.xx:5000/bower/angular/angular.min.js?version=1.4.7:117:315)
    at n.a.$get.n.$watch (http://52.29.xx.xx:5000/bower/angular/angular.min.js?version=1.4.7:127:125)
    at a.link (http://52.29.xx.xx:5000/bower/angular/angular.min.js?version=1.4.7:254:214)
    at aa (http://52.29.xx.xx:5000/bower/angular/angular.min.js?version=1.4.7:73:90)
```

Any how I can check if `the_key` exists in `the_object` from within the ng-if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the property you want to check is inside your object and not the inherited one, you can use below code.

`<span ng-if="the_object.hasOwnProperty('the_key')">
    the_key exists in the_object
</span>`

If above is not the case and you make sure that you don't initalize `the_key` undefined in your object, you can use below code:

`<span ng-if="the_object['the_key'] !== undefined">
    the_key exists in the_object
</span>`

check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XEiHAct97uOj3HKaJr1N?p=preview)

If you make sure, you don't initialize any value of your object undefined, the second approach is way faster than the first one. Check more about this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/22074727/3292746

Comment: It works! But why?! Do you know why the normal javascript I try to use doesn't work? I thought Angular simply takes the code between the quotes and evaluates it as js?

Comment: It is because, ng-if expect angular expression and angular-expression is not same as javascript expression.  Know more about Angular Expression at (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). And as per that it doesn't allow void expressoin.But it works. Its is better to use undefined instead of void(0).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check

`ng-if="the_object.the_key !== undefined"`

it check `the_key` exist or not in `the_object`. if exist it return `true` and if not exist it return `false`. exist means not undefined.

Comment: That is not the same. What if `the_object.the_key` is `false` or `null`?

Comment: ok, updated my code.  if you check `!== undefined` then it will work like that you want .