# Javascript - check if key exists - if not create it, all in one line

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a one-liner way of checking if a key exists and if it doesn't create it.

```
var myObject = {};

//Anyway to do the following in a simpler fashion?

if (!('myKey' in myObject))
{
    myObject['myKey'] = {};
}
```

Comment: there are plenty of ways of detecting if an object has a key, as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1098955/6496271)

Comment: Problem is not how to find that a key exists or not.. problem is a short one line code to add a property if it does not exist.

Answer (score 43):

Short circuit evaluation:

```
!('myKey' in myObject) && (myObject.myKey = {})
```

Comment: both clever and reliable

Comment: Just be aware inherited properties will be picked up by this too. hasOwnProperty should be used if that's not desired.

Comment: Of course, you could get rid of a character by using *or* ;  `('myKey' in myObject) || (myObject.myKey={})`

Comment: @BotNet this solution is even more readable if you think about it literally

Answer (score 37):

```
myObject['myKey'] = myObject['myKey'] || {};
```

Comment: While not an issue in some cases, for "falsy" values (`0`, `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `''`, etc) you will overwrite `myKey`

Comment: Nice catch! @Nindaff

Comment: @ShrikanthBuds |= is a bitwise operator and doesn't give the same result as the expression in the answer. There is no shorthand assignment operator for logical or like this: ||=

Comment: On the other hand this method is safe for `localStorage`, while using `Object.assign` is not.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the Logical nullish assignment (??=)

```
var test = {};
(test.hello ??= {}).world ??= "Hello doesn't exist!";
```

Comment: reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment

Answer (score 8):

Comment:
I generally prefer the answers provided by [@Nindaff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38034202/914600) and [@MoustafaS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38034195/914600), depending on the circumstances.

For completeness, you can create key/values, using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for any keys that did not exist.  This is most useful when you have default options/settings you want to use, but allow users to overwrite via arguments.  It'd look like this:

```
var myObject = {};
myObject = Object.assign( { 'myKey':{} }, myObject );
```

Here's the same thing with a little more output:

```js
var obj = {};
console.log( 'initialized:', obj);


obj = Object.assign( {'foo':'one'}, obj );
console.log( 'foo did not exist:', obj );

obj = Object.assign( {'foo':'two'}, obj );
console.log( 'foo already exists:', obj );


delete obj.foo;
obj = Object.assign( {'foo':'two'}, obj );
console.log( 'foo did not exist:', obj );
```

Note: *Object.assign* is not available in IE, but there's a Polyfill

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the value for a certain key *and* insert a new default value for that key *if* it doesn't exist and return that default value, then here you go in a single line:

```
> x = {}
{}
> x['k']
undefined
> x['k'] ?? (x['k'] = 23) // Insert default value for non-existent key
23
> x['k']
23
> x['z'] = 5
5
> x['z'] ?? (x['z'] = 42) // Will not insert default value because key exists
5
```

With the [new nullish assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) this can be simplified to:

```
x['k'] ??= 23
```

Obviously you need to add some extra work for keys which can map to `null`.

Comment: In 2021, I suggest using `??` instead of `||` so `false` and friends don't get replaced.

Comment: Good suggestion! Also added an example for the new nullish assignment operator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use hasOwnProperty or typeof for checking exits or undefine...

Comment: Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(myObject, 'myKey');

Answer (score 1):

There is a designated [`Proxy`](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-proxies-in-depth) internal type that's suitable for this task:

```
const myObj = new Proxy({}, {
  get (target, key) {
    return target.hasOwnProperty(key) && target[key] || (target[key] = {});
  }
});

typeof myObj.foo === 'object' && (myObj.bar.quux = 'norf') && myObj.bar.quux === 'norf';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()`, `Object.hasOwnProperty()`

```js
var key = {myKey:{}}, prop = Object.keys(key).pop(), myObject = {}; if (!myObject.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {myObject[prop] = key[prop]}
console.log(myObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript ES9 (ECMAScript 2018) introduced the spread operator:

```
myObject={myKey: {}, ...myObject}
```

`myKey` will be created if it doesn't already exist but wont be overwritten if it does. For example:

```
let obj = {a:1,b:2}

let test1 = {...obj,a:3} // == {a:3,b:2}
let test1 = {a:1,b:2,a:3} // == {a:3,b:2}

let test2 = {a:3,...obj} // == {a:1,b:2}
let test2 = {a:3,a:1,b:2} // == {a:1,b:2}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know whether or not the key of the object exists you you can do something like

```
object.key = (object.key || default value) operation
```

Example

```
const user = {};

user.stat = (user.stat || 0) + 1; // 1
```

And if you were to call this expression multiple times you'd get the expected behaviour

Example

```
const user = {};

user.stat = (user.stat || 0) + 1; // 1
user.stat = (user.stat || 0) + 1; // 2
user.stat = (user.stat || 0) + 1; // 3
```

Its effectively the same using a ternary operator like so

```
user.stat = user.stat ? user.stat + 1 : 0;
```

but more compact