# Iterating through object properties returns all object properties

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a json that looks like this:

```
        "metrics" : {
            "ga:pageviews" : true,
            "bounceRate" : false
        }
```

which is sub object of a bigger json. I access that object like this:

```
var metrics = report.specifications[0]
```

I am trying to iterate through these two properties like this:

```
    for(var key in metrics) {
        if (metrics.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log(key + " -> " + metrics[key]);
        }
    }
```

Although, instead of getting these two properties i get a very big list with other properties of the object.

The first line of the unlimited list i get is:

```
__parentArray -> { metrics: { 'ga:pageviews': true, bounceRate: false } }
```

Does this has to do with my issue?

Whole JSON schema looks like this:

```
reportId: String,
specifications : [{
    metrics: {
        'ga:pageviews': Boolean,
        bounceRate: Boolean
    },
    dimensions: {

    }
}
]
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object

Comment: No idea. That code should only be iterating two properties, assuming your `metrics` object is what you assume it to be. Not enough info in the question to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Yeah its strange i get an unlimited list instead

Comment: Unlimited? Or just very long? What are they key names. Do you recognize them at all? Seems like you're just working with some other property or object altogether.

Comment: @squint check edit

Comment: As I can assume you working on 1 level  higher than you need. Try: var metrics = report.specifications[0].metrics;

Comment: @Nosyara I tried i get a different long list

Comment: @Nosyara The last lines look like this now 
bounceRate -> false
ga:pageviews -> true
id -> undefined
_id -> undefined
dimensions -> undefined
metrics -> undefined

Comment: I'm guessing you're just logging an entire object somewhere. Probably getting a lot of properties with leading underscores, right? I think NodeJS may show inherited properties when logging objects. Is this actually affecting your code?

Comment: @squint I dont think so the only logging i do is that one

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding the toObject() method here:

```
    var metrics = report.specifications[0].metrics.toObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to iterate through properties in JavaScript is using `Object.keys`. The difference between doing this and using a `for` loop is that `Object.keys` ignores properties in the prototype chain, which you are probably picking up.

```
Object.keys(metrics).forEach(function (key) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + metrics[key]);
});
```

Comment: Incorrect answer previously -- pardon me; that was a lazy copy-paste attempt. It is useful to know about the difference between a for loop and Object.keys, though.