# Extract words repeating from CKeditor textarea

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I still working on a jQuery script that output under the Ckeditor the list of the most repeated words.
Is not a keywords density but just a list of words and their repeats, excluding stop words both in english and Italian, plus some html clean-out.
Is based on Bootstrap, jQuery and Ckeditor.

I've made this JSFiddle example that works good: https://jsfiddle.net/wzh7c42f/

the problem is if I wrote in any position inside a text in textarea the word "map" the function KeyDensityShow raise an error, and to be precise in the line

```
word_counts[positions[word]][1]++
```

I've not found a solution or why it give an error.
If someone could help out to find the reason and provide a fix or a better optimization I will be very grateful.

ty in advance

---

**EDIT:**

Using the provided solution i fixed my code and works perfectly.
this is the functional version on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/09m7c2hw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens because you're comparing the type of the key array to `undefined`, which is not wrong ([as we already saw here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1098955/1269558)):

```
if (typeof positions[word] == 'undefined') {
```

However, it fails when the key name is a reserved word (like `map` -  a valid JavaScript function), because it'll always return the function itself, even if it's not present into the array.

### Solution:

Change the snipet to the following:

```
if (!positions.hasOwnProperty(word)) {
    positions[word] = word_counts.length;
    word_counts.push([word, 1]);
} else {
    word_counts[positions[word]][1]++;
}
```

---

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

> This method can be used to determine whether an object has the
>   specified property as a direct property of that object; **unlike the *in*
>   operator, this method does not check down the object's prototype
>   chain.**

Comment: thank you so much, i suspected that was that kind of error. The solutionyou provided is perfect i've updated the main post to leave the new JSFiddle code for future use.