# how to check whether string is availble in array or not

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one array

```
var arr = ["abc=0","def=2","ghi=3","jkl=6","mno=9"];
```

Now I want to check whether "ghi" and "mno" is there or not in array. If there then what is the value.

Comment: this might be a duplicate, check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object)

Comment: It's var arr = ["abc=0","def=2","ghi=3","jkl=6","mno=9"]; or var arr = [abc="0",def="2",ghi="3",jkl="6",mno="9"]; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to do it:

```js
    var arr = ["abc=0","def=2","ghi=3","jkl=6","mno=9"];
    
    for(var child in arr){
        console.log(arr[child].includes("mno"));
    }
```

Edit, for old browser you can do it this way:

```js
var arr = ["abc=0","def=2","ghi=3","jkl=6","mno=9"];
    
    for(var child in arr){
        console.log(arr[child].search("mno"));
    }
```

Where 0 is equal to true ^^

Comment: added IE11 version ^^

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr = ["abc=0","def=2","ghi=3","jkl=6","mno=9"];

function valueOf (array, key) {
  var value;
  if (array.find(function (item) {
    return ([ , value ] = item.split("="))[0] === key
  })) {
    return value;
  }
}

console.log(valueOf(arr, "ghi")); // 3
console.log(valueOf(arr, "mno")); // 9
console.log(valueOf(arr, "foo")); // undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com)

```
var arr = ["abc=0","def=2","ghi=3","jkl=6","mno=9"];
var r = _.find(arr, function(i) { return i.includes('ghi'); });
alert(r);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ea1ta9rp/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```
arr.find(function(item) {
    if(typeof item === "string" && item.includes("asd")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Now if an item was found, you can assume that the string was found in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array and check each string.

```js
function searchStringInArray (str, strArray) {
    for (var j=0; j<strArray.length; j++) {
        if (strArray[j].match(str)) return j;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

```js
var arr = ["abc=0","def=2","ghi=3","jkl=6","mno=9"];
 
 function searchStringInArray (str, strArray) {
    for (var j=0; j<strArray.length; j++) {
        if (strArray[j].match(str)) return j;
    }
    return -1;
}

var pos_of_ghi = searchStringInArray("ghi", arr );
var pos_of_mno = searchStringInArray("mno", arr );
if(pos_of_ghi ==-1){
alert("ghi not found")
}
else{
alert("pos_of_ghi="+pos_of_ghi);
}

if(pos_of_mno ==-1){
alert("mno not found")
}
else{
alert("pos_of_mno="+pos_of_mno);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the best and simple logic is:

```
arr.find(function(item) {
   return (typeof item === "string" && item.includes("ghi"));
});
```