# How can I add a key value pair to the end of a JSON list if I don't know which keys already exist?

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say I have a JSON list like this:

`var obj = {"1": "somevalue", "2": "someothervalue"};`

How can I add `{"3": "somevalue"}` to the object **dynamically**? i.e. without knowing that two keys already that exist.

I'm looking for some JavaScript that looks at the JSON list, then adds a key to the end without accidentally overwriting an existing key.

I understand there is a similar question here: [Checking if a key exists in a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object) but I would like to know how to dynamically generate the next number key e.g. "3" in the example above.

Comment: Also important to note there's no such thing as adding a key to the "end". Objects' keys are unordered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a key exists in a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object)

Comment: If the title was true, you'd have a lot harder time, as you'd have to do either string processing or `JSON.parse()` before checking for the existence of the key. That may look like valid JSON, but that is a JavaScript object literal, and so it is not actually serialized even though it is serialized in the source code.

Comment: Use an array instead of an object, and use the built-in push method.  Arrays *are* ordered, and have indices.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply

```
 if(typeof obj[key] !== 'undefined') {
   obj[key] = value
 }
```

So in your script it would be better to have it wrapped in a function such like

```
function appendObj(obj, key, value) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'undefined') { // lets make sure there is an obj first
   if(typeof key!=='undefined' && key && typeof obj[key] !== 'undefined') {
     obj[key] = value;
   }
   else {
    obj.push(value);
   }
  }
}
```

then whenever you need to add a K/V to any object,

```
var myNewObj = {"1": "somevalue", "2": "someothervalue"};
appendObj(myNewObj, '4', 'new value')
```

Comment: Can you please explain your condition checking?

Comment: I'd probably go for something more like `if(!(key in obj))` for the conditional

Comment: @RyanSpeets `in` isn't reliable. Rather `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` would be best here.

Comment: @AR7 I wouldn't say that `in` isn't reliable, the difference between it and `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` is that it also returns `true` for `prototype` properties

Comment: @AkashKC because OP asks  not to override data if same key exists in object already.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you expand on it a bit? I'm a JS newbie and struggling to connect the dots. The following just gets me a "key is not defined" error `var obj = {"1": "somevalue", "2": "somevalue"}; if(typeof obj[key] !== 'undefined') {
   obj[key] = 'something'
 }`

Comment: `key` in that case is is the index you will be passing, see my update.

Comment: But that would not be dynamically generating a key? My point is that I'm not sure what it needs to be, and it would depend on the last key. So if there are 2 keys, literally `"1": "somevalue", "2", "someothervalue"` then I need to dynamically set the 3rd key to be "3"

Comment: Yes and no. If you just want to append a value, you don't need to pass a key nor you need to check it's existence because new item you push will get next available key. but if you want to pass a key and value and want to check to avoid overriding then you need to check existence first then append if it doesn't. makes sense?

Comment: Oh ok! I didn't realise it will generate a the next available key automatically. Thanks

Comment: I want to define my object with `{ 1: undefined, 2: undefined }` and _not_ override them, thank you very much :|

Answer (score 4):

you can use `in` to check if key exists in object.

```
if (!(key in obj))
   obj[key] = 'somevalue'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you fancy libraries that help you with this, you can use assign from *lodash*:

```
var obj = {"1": "somevalue", "2": "someothervalue"};
var obj2 = {"3": "somevalue"};

_.assign(obj, obj2); // Was called _.extend in older versions
```

Answer (score -3):

check and see if the property exists

```
if(! obj[key]) { 
  obj[key] = value;
}
```

Comment: This overwrites falsey keys such as 0, false, null