# How to check if local storage key does not exist?

Tags: angular, typescript

I can find if the local storage key exists or not using the if condition in the below code

```
    this.data = localStorage.getItem('education'); 
      if(this.data)//check if it exists or not empty
{
        console.log("Exists");
      }
```

If want to use if condition to find if it does not exist, how do I write that in code? I don't want to use else.

Comment: You mean by negating the condition in the code? `if (!(this.data)) { console.log("DOH!"); }`

Comment: worked thanks, please write answer so i can acccept

Comment: I'll do it! Thank you!

Comment: please accept my question also if it is clearly understood

Comment: I'm sorry but does not exist something like "accepting the question". Questions can be only upvoted or downvoted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if value exist in Local Storage data set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47167393/how-to-check-if-value-exist-in-local-storage-data-set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `this.data` is `undefined`, than `!(this.data)` should work:

```
if (!(this.data)) { console.log("DOH!"); }
```

Edit: I just received a comment that raises a point. What if the key is `false`? It is not enough. What if the key actually exists and it is set to `undefined`? Then the method will fail. Thus probably it is better to use the `in` keyword (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1098955/2319299))

```
if (!("data" in this)) { console.log("DOH!"); }
```

as for example:

```
obj = { a: false, b: undefined }
if (!("a" in obj)) { console.log("a does not exist"); }
if (!("b" in obj)) { console.log("b does not exist"); }
if (!("c" in obj)) { console.log("c does not exist"); }
```

The output is

```
c does not exist
```

Comment: This will fail if the value is false and you want to set it to "true" by default. Better to check if this.data is undefined and then act.

Comment: you're right. I fixed it. It is still  bad idea to check if it is undefined. What if a key is undefined then?

Comment: You're right too :) For my example I wanted the value to start to "true" if it wasn't setted. But your example covers all the scenarios. Good work