# Object[key] vs Array.filter(elem => elem[key] === key)

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a humongous set of objects which can either be represented as

```
const object = {
    <SOME_KEY_0>: {
        type: <SOME_TYPE>,
        value: <SOME_VALUE>
    },
    <SOME_KEY_1>: {
        type: <SOME_TYPE>,
        value: <SOME_VALUE>
    },
    // so on...
}

return object[<SOME_KEY_1>];
```

or as

```
const array = [
    {
        key: <SOME_KEY_0>,
        type: <SOME_TYPE>,
        value: <SOME_VALUE>
    },
    {
        key: <SOME_KEY_1>,
        type: <SOME_TYPE>,
        value: <SOME_VALUE>
    },
    // so on...
]

return array.filter(elem => elem.key === <SOME_KEY_1>);
```

Which structure would be more efficient in finding a specific object identifiable by the `key`?

Also, we can assume `array.filter()` can be replaced with a **for-loop** to allow premature break.

Comment: `x[y]` is faster.

Comment: it's fastest to iterate an array, rather than an objects enumerable keys

Comment: Might be the good reference.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object

Comment: Your first structure would be more efficient if you are finding all elements by the key (probably less than `O(n)`, depends on the implementation of the browser.)

Comment: I will be running this on node.js server-side and all elements will be looked up by the *key* and *key only*. Looks like object key reference is more favored.
But what if I have to build the object/array, would it be similar in performance if I do `array[i] = stuff` or `object[key] = stuff`?

Comment: Use first approach ; Object.keys() will return an array; try filter on top of that array;