# How to check if key exists in array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to find out if the given key exists in array of object. if the value key exists then i want to return true else false.

i giving input of key from text box and then checking if the key exists in array of objects, but i couldn't get it.

here is what i have tried

code:

```
var obj = [{
    "7364234":"hsjd",
    "tom and jerry":"dsjdas",
    "mickey mouse":"kfjskdsad",
    "popeye the sailor man":"alkdsajd",
    "the carribean":"kasjdsjad"
}]

var val = $("input[name='type_ahead_input']").val();

if (obj[val]) {
    console.log('exists');
} else {
    console.log('does not exist');
}
```

if i give input as '`the carribean`' which exists in array of object, even then its outputting in console as does not exist.

how can i resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a key exists in a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object) and `if (val in obj[0]) {`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `typeof` to check if `key` exist

```
if (typeof obj[0][val] !== "undefined" ) {
    console.log('exists');
} else {
    console.log('does not exist');
}
```

Note: There is index `0` coz the object that you are checking is an element 0 of the array `obj`

---

Here is a fiddle:

```js
var obj = [{
  "7364234":"hsjd",
  "tom and jerry":"dsjdas",
  "mickey mouse":"kfjskdsad",
  "popeye the sailor man":"alkdsajd",
  "the carribean":"kasjdsjad"
 }];

 if ( typeof obj[0]["the carribean"] !== 'undefined' ) {
  console.log('exists');
 } else {
  console.log('does not exist');
 }
```

---

As suggested by Cristy below, you can also use `obj[0][val] === undefined`

You can also:

```
var obj = [{
    "7364234":"hsjd",
    "tom and jerry":"dsjdas",
    "mickey mouse":"kfjskdsad",
    "popeye the sailor man":"alkdsajd",
    "the carribean":"kasjdsjad"
}];

var val = "7364234";

if ( val in obj[0] ) {
    console.log('exists');
} else {
    console.log('does not exist');
}
```

Comment: `obj[0][val] === undefined` is easier to read/write/understand. Also note, that a key can exist even if the value is undefined. The `in` operator should be used instead: `val in obj[0]`

Comment: This solution fails if there are multiple objects in the array.

Answer (score 13):

You can filter the objects array and return only the objects which have the desired key. Then if the resulting array has a length greater than zero, it means that there are elements having that key.

```
var obj = [{
    "7364234":"hsjd",
    "tom and jerry":"dsjdas",
    "mickey mouse":"kfjskdsad",
    "popeye the sailor man":"alkdsajd",
    "the carribean":"kasjdsjad"
}];

var val = "the carribean";

var exists = obj.filter(function (o) {
  return o.hasOwnProperty(val);
}).length > 0;

if (exists) {
    console.log('exists');
} else {
    console.log('does not exist');
}
```

This will return `true` if the array contains objects which have the desired key no matter if its value is `undefined` or `null`.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using `Array.some()` to know if a key exists and  `Array.find()` to get the value of the found key, together with some recent syntax:

```js
let arr = [{"foo": 1}, {"bar":2}];

function isKeyInArray(array, key) { 
  return array.some(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(key)); 
}

function getValueFromKeyInArray(array, key) { 
  return array.find(obj => obj[key])?.[key]; 
}

console.log(isKeyInArray(arr, "foo"), isKeyInArray(arr, "bar"), isKeyInArray(arr, "baz"));
console.log(getValueFromKeyInArray(arr, "foo"), getValueFromKeyInArray(arr, "bar"), getValueFromKeyInArray(arr, "baz"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `obj` is an array so to detect if the key exists in any of the objects in the *array* you need to iterate the array for then look at each object's keys.

```js
var objArr = [{
  "7364234": "hsjd",
  "tom and jerry": "dsjdas",
  "mickey mouse": "kfjskdsad",
  "popeye the sailor man": "alkdsajd",
  "the carribean": "kasjdsjad"
}]

const contains = (string) =>
  objArr.findIndex(
    // Is the string contained in the object keys?
    obj => Object.keys(obj).includes(string)
  ) !== -1

console.log(contains('the carribean'))
console.log(contains('spaghetti'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have an array of objects `[{...},{...}]` and not just an object `{...}`.
Either use an object and keep your test, or use the Array.find method to search if an object with the `val`property exists in you array. Ex :

```
var objArr = [{
    "7364234":"hsjd",
    "tom and jerry":"dsjdas",
    "mickey mouse":"kfjskdsad",
    "popeye the sailor man":"alkdsajd",
    "the carribean":"kasjdsjad"
}]

let val = $("input[name='type_ahead_input']").val();

var existingObj = objArr.find(function(element) {
  return typeof element[val] !== 'undefined';
});

if (existingObj[val]) {
console.log('was found');
} else {
console.log('not-found');
```

See : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/find

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the object from the array `obj[0][val]`

```js
var validate = function() {
  var obj = [{
    "7364234": "hsjd",
    "tom and jerry": "dsjdas",
    "mickey mouse": "kfjskdsad",
    "popeye the sailor man": "alkdsajd",
    "the carribean": "kasjdsjad"
  }];

  var val = $("input[name='type_ahead_input']").val();
  console.log(val);
  if (obj[0][val]) {
    console.log('exists');
  } else {
    console.log('does not exist');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="type_ahead_input" value="" onkeyup="validate()">
```

Answer (score 0):

@E. Sundin answer is the simplest I think. For my case, I was done like below ...

```js
let o = { 
    id: 2, 
    name: "jack", 
    age: 54, temp: 2323
}

if(!Object.keys(o).includes('id')) throw new BadRequest("Id was missing!");
```

If you have an array of objects done by a loop through.

```js
if(!o.every(elm => Object.keys(o).includes('id')) throw new BadRequest("Id was missing!");
```

Hopefully, it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
const array = [{ name:'Stark' }, { email:'stark@gmail.com' }, { roll: '14' }]

const result = array.some(item => item.hasOwnProperty('email'))

console.log('Does Email Exist: ', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Boolean(array.find(el => el.searchKey) // true or false
```

Simple way to check if key exists inside array of objects.