# ngOnChanges causing error until async function is complete Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have a function that happens on the lifecycle event `ngOnChanges`, now the function works fine but when the app first loads it throws an error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined` now I know the reason is because the data its trying to read the property from hasn't arrived yet but then obviously when the data is there it works.. this is my function

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.contentfulService.getWeekItems(this.item.fields.week)
      .then((weekItems) => {
        this.weekItems = weekItems;
      }).then(() => {
        this.numberOfItems = this.weekItems.length;
  });
 }
```

now I know if I was in my `component.html` I could do something like this.. `"item?.fields?..."` is there an equivalent for inside your `.ts` file?

Comment: you can check if the property `fields` exists or not?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object

Comment: @swetanshkumar The property fields does exist, but the item hasnt been returned yet, thus when the page is loaded the first 'change', there is nothing there which is why the error is being called and then on the next change when the data has come back obviously the error goes away

Comment: that is why I told you to add a check if value exists ? This will  prevent the console from throwing error as `undefined`.

Comment: @swetanshkumar could you explain how I apply this in my situation?

Comment: `this.numberOfItems = this.weekItems && this.weekitems.length`
unfortunately there is no null coalescing operator in typescript

Comment: @Jim how does that solve my problem?

Comment: it doesn't sorry, I did not read carefully enough, I will come back with a better suggestion. what does your html look like? can you not just check whether or not `item.fields` exists in an `if` statement before calling `getWeekItems`

Answer (score 2):

There is no Null coalescing operator in typescript yet. Refer: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16

However,

`this.item?.fields` is equivalent to `this.item && this.item.fields`