# If property undefined or does not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Need a little help. I have an array of properties that I filter on. However, if a property does not exist my view does not render because that properties becomes undefined. I need to gracefully ignore or show some other value.

```
export const countryList = [
    {name: 'France', flagCode: 'fr'},
    {name: 'England', flagCode: 'england'},
    {name: 'Germany', flagCode: 'gm'},
    {name: 'default', flagCode: 'default'},
];

const country = `${nationality}`
const flag = countryList.filter(function (el) {
    return el.name.toLowerCase() === country.toLowerCase();
})[0].flagCode;
```

So if `${nationality}` returned "Italy", `.flagCode` would return `undefined`. I could add Italy to my array to solve this however there will be countries I miss and need a more graceful approached. So In my function I need to check if `undefined`, if it is then return a default name of 'default', if it does exist then return the value from the array.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: show the code from `view`

Comment: ".flagCode would return undefined" it would actually throw.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object/22074727#22074727

Comment: Also, if you're expecting only one match then `.filter` is the wrong method. Use `.find` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `some` to check existence first, if it's `false`, directly assign a `default`, else, run your `filter` code

```js
let countryList = [
  {name: 'France', flagCode: 'fr'},
  {name: 'England', flagCode: 'england'},
  {name: 'Germany', flagCode: 'gm'},
  {name: 'default', flagCode: 'default'},
];

const country = `Italy`;
let flag = "";

if(countryList.some(x=>x.name === country)){
  flag = countryList.filter(function (el) {
       return el.name.toLowerCase() === country.toLowerCase();
     })[0].flagCode;
}else{
  flag = "default"
}

console.log(flag);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an OR operator `||` to do this

```
const country = countryList.find(el => (el.name.toLowerCase() === country.toLowerCase());

const flag = (country && country.flagCode) || 'default';
```

Comment: This makes no sense. `map` returns new array. OP wants to get a string.

Comment: well if it's not found then yeah :D we can add a simple validation if needed `(country && country.flagCode)`

Answer (score 1):

```
const country = countryList.filter(function (el) {
    return el.name.toLowerCase() === country.toLowerCase();
})[0];
```

you can use default values

```
const flag = country.flagCode || 'default';
```

OR you can use ternary operators as well, which is again the same thing as above

```
const flag = !!country.flagCode ? country.flagCode : 'default';
```