# Javascript search and group items from object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Here is my sample object:

```
name: 'Jango',
age: 23,
sex: 'male',
phone_0: '0000000',
phone_1: '1111111',
phone_2: '2222222'
```

on the above object, I want to look for is there any field exist with 'phone_', if exist, I want them to be plucked to another array or object.

How to do this in Javascript?

Note: I am inside a react component.

Comment: [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the object into array using `Object.entries`. Use `reduce` to loop thru the array. Use `includes` to check if the string contains a substring.

```js
let obj = {
  name: 'Jango',
  age: 23,
  sex: 'male',
  phone_0: '0000000',
  phone_1: '1111111',
  phone_2: '2222222'
}

let result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((c, [k, v]) => {
  if (k.includes('phone_')) c[k] = v;
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

You can also use if you want to check if `phone_` is in the start of the key.

```
substr( k, 0, 6 ) === "phone_"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const required = _.pick(Object.keys(item).filter(
    key=> key.startsWith(‘phone_’)
    );
```

_ is lodash library.