# Check if nested key exists even if undefined

Tags: javascript, lodash

Trying to figure out what the easiest way to write a function `keyExisits` that checks and arbitrarily nested key to see if it exists in an object and is undefined, vs does not exisit.

assume this obj

```
var obj = {
  a: {
    b: 1,
    c: {
      d: 2,
      e: undefined
    }
  }
}
```

In this object the key `a.c.e` exists and is `undefined`, the key `a.c.f` does not exist

so

```
keyExists(obj, 'a.c.e') === true
keyExists(obj, 'a.c.f') === false
```

using lodash/underscore is ok

** UPDATE **

Lodash `has` works exactly like this

Comment: Disagree since this question is specific for nested keys. Answers on the linked question don't provide solutions.

Comment: This is a different question.

Comment: Anyways, check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key

Comment: @Andrey its still a duplicate of how to check if a key exists, even if implementing recursion is needed the underlying question is the same

Comment: **[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43096892)**

Comment: @riv See above.

Comment: And lodash has `_.has` method https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#has

Comment: @Andrey See above.

Comment: key.split(".").reduce(function(acc,cur){ return (acc[cur] || "")}, obj); then just check for ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following

```js
var obj = {a: {b: 1,c: {d: 2,e: undefined}}};

function keyExists(o, key) {
  if(key.includes(".")) {
    let [k, ...rest] = key.split(".");
    return keyExists(o[k], rest.join("."));
  } else if(o) {
    return o.hasOwnProperty(key);
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(keyExists(obj, 'a.c.e') === true)
console.log(keyExists(obj, 'a.c.f') === false)
```

**Note**: The above code will not work if there are any `dots` in the `key name` or you are using `[]` notation.

Comment: Performance wise, this seems quite counter productive to join the key just to split it again. It will also throw an `cannot read property of undefined` error if an intermediate key does not exist, i.e. `keyExists(obj, 'b.c.e')`.