# how to check if a object in an array contains a key or not in React

Tags: javascript

I am a novice to React and I am stuck in something. I have an array in the state which contains an object in it. The array looks like this:

```
myVar = [
      {
      "a": 1,
      "b":2
  },
  {
    "c":1,
    "d":1
  },
  {
    "e":"",
    "f":4
  }
  ];
```

I want to check somehow that does the array contains a key `a` or `c` or `f` by using `this.state.myVar` syntax. It doesn't matter what value it contains. It can be null.

I couldn't find a way to check it using JSX.

My output depends on it. Like if the array contains a key called `a or c or f` then it will display data depending on the available key. I can do this part but not sure how can I check for the availability of the key. Please Help me on that.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it has nothing to do with React, JSX or another thing other than JavaScript itself. You can check if any of array items contains a key with the snippet below;

`arr.some(item => item.hasOwnProperty('propertyName')) // returns boolean`

So it will be something as below for your case;

`myVar.some(item => item.hasOwnProperty('a'))`

You can check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx) out to see how you can use the code in JSX.

Answer (score 5):

> I couldn't find a way to check it using JSX.

This is not related to JSX or React. You need to iterate the array and check.

---

You can use any loop and [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check whether the object has that key or not.
One possible way to check is using [#Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Like this:

```js
myVar = [
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b":2
  },
  {
    "c":1,
    "d":1
  },
  {
    "e":"",
    "f":4
  }
];

let isKeyPresent = myVar.some(el => {
  if(el.hasOwnProperty('a') || el.hasOwnProperty('b') || el.hasOwnProperty('f'))
    return true;
})

console.log('isKeyPresent', isKeyPresent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go through each array element by mapping it.

For example

`myVar.map( function(item){ console.log(item) } )`

Now you can check if the object `item` contains any of the required keys by using any one of the methods mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object).
One method is as follows:

```
`myVar.map( function(item){ 
   if("a" in item){
    ...
   }
 })`
```