# How to use 'if' in the case of that it is true if one data is included in an array by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have a question whether this is possible or not.
For example, there is one code like below. But that code has an error for sure.
And I want to make `if` is `true` when one data is at some array.
Could you recommend some method?

This is my code:

```
var a = 1;
var model2 = [1, 2, 3];
if (a == model2) {
    var b = a;
} else {
    var c = a;
}
```

Comment: `{1, 2, 3}` is neither an array nor an object, it's causes a syntax error in this case. What is `model2` supposed to be? An array?

Comment: First, is `model2` supposed to be `[1, 2, 3]`? If so, are you trying to find an item in the array?

Comment: You can try to use a dictionary. This might help: [Checking if a key exists in a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Yes. I am sorry. I made a mistake and changed that for making an arryay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the structure, I believe that `model2` is meant to be an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Arrays are created with the `[]` square brackets rather than the `{}` curly braces, which are used for code blocks and objects. `model2` should look like this:

```
var model2 = [1, 2, 3];
```

As for checking whether something is within an array, you would use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
if (model2.includes(a)) {...}
```

What `.includes()` does is check, does the array (`model2`) *include* the passed variable/value (`a`), and returns a Boolean value (`true` or `false`) depending on whether the value actually is in the array.

Full working code:

```
var a = 1;
var model2 = [1, 2, 3];
if (model2.includes(a)) {
    var b = a;
}
else {
    var c = a;
}
```

Further reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

you're not creating an array with var model2 = {1, 2, 3}, you should define as

```
var model2 = [1,2,3]
```

Case you wanna use arrays.
then you can just use the include method

```
if(model2.includes(a)){
  var b = a
}else{
  var c = a
}
```

It should help!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly this isn't an array but an object and a broken one to boot.
Arrays are defined with `[ ]` brackets.

Now to your question. Arrays have a prototype function called `.includes()`

Read up on it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Mind you, this isn't supported by IE11 so if this is a priority to you let me know and I'll update this answer.

Comment: _"... you will most likely have to resort to looping through each item of the array"_. That's not the only way, OP could use the widely supported `indexOf` and check if the return value is not `-1`: `.indexOf(a) !== -1`.