# Removing elements from array based on existence of a key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object that I have converted to an array
using this

```
convertToArray(data: any) {
  let arr = [];
  Object.keys(data).map(function(key){
     arr.push(data[key]);
  });
  return arr;
}
```

Here is the result

```
{0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, hideTitle: false, template: "football-news", customProperties: {…}}
0: {NewsID: 90, AnotherAttribute: 5, …}
1: {NewsID: 90, AnotherAttribute: 5, …}
2: {NewsID: 90, AnotherAttribute: 5, …}
customProperties: {template: "list-view"}
hideTitle: false
template: "news"
__proto__: Object
```

*to*

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, false, "football-news", {…}]
0: {NewsID: 90, AnotherAttribute: 5, …}
1: {NewsID: 90, AnotherAttribute: 5, …}
2: {NewsID: 90, AnotherAttribute: 5, …}
3: false
4: "news"
5: {template: "list-view"}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I want to remove any items (arr.pop or filter) that DOESNT have a NewsID key.

I appreciate any help in advance :)

Comment: Add input as text please not as images

Comment: Do you want me to copy 200 lines of JSON in here?, I dont mind, but the jJSONon itself isn't my problem, I took a screenshot to help to understand

Comment: You can create a dummy data mate, no need of posting your full json. this will help people to answer quickly and accurately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` with destructuring assignment to filter out values which are undefined by only keeping objects where the `NewsID` gives a truthy value (here `NewsID` will be undefined if it does not exist, and thus falsey).

Moreover, you can refine your `convertToArray` method by using `Object.values()`. There is no need to loop over your keys/values twice.

See working example below:

```js
function convertToArray(data) {
  return Object.values(data);
}

const myObj = {
  0: {
    NewsID: 90,
    AnotherAttribute: 5
  },
  1: {
    NewsID: 90,
    AnotherAttribute: 5
  },
  2: {
    NewsID: 90,
    AnotherAttribute: 5
  },
  customProperties: {
    template: "list-view"
  },
  hideTitle: false,
  template: "news"
},
arr = convertToArray(myObj),

res = arr.filter(({NewsID}) => NewsID);
console.log(res);
```

**Note**:

- If your `NewsID` can be `0` then you should check using `.filter(({NewsID}) => NewsID !== undefined)`.
- If your `NewsID` can have an explicit value of `undefined` (eg: you use `{NewsID: undefined}`) you should use `.filter((obj) => obj instanceof Object && "NewsID" in obj)`

Comment: Nick i guess you don't need `NewsID !== undefined`, +1 for explanation

Comment: perfectly done! thank you ! it works like a charm :)

Comment: @JohnMersal no worries!

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood your question because printouts as images are really hard to read.

---

So it looks like you have a list of objects and you want to remove ones that don't have a certain key, correct?

You can it in following manner:

```
result = arr.filter(obj => "NewsID" in obj)
```

If you want to learn more about how to check if an object has a key, this looks like good place to start: [Checking if a key exists in a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple Boolean filter upon `Object.values` of the object:

```js
const data = {
  0: {
    NewsID: 90,
    AnotherAttribute: 5
  },
  1: {
    NewsID: 90,
    AnotherAttribute: 5
  },
  2: {
    NewsID: 90,
    AnotherAttribute: 5
  },
  customProperties: {
    template: "list-view"
  },
  hideTitle: false,
  template: "news"
};

const arr = Object.values(data).filter(({ NewsID }) => NewsID);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array which has values of diffrent types and  diffrent types of object.
First you need to check whether value in array is instance of a object or not.

```
function convertToArray(data) {
  let arr = [];
  Object.keys(data).map(function(key){
     arr.push(data[key]);
  });
  return arr;
}
var obj = {
   0:  { NewsID: 90, AnotherAttribute: 5},
   1: {NewsID: 90, AnotherAttribute: 5}, 
   2: {NewsID: 90, AnotherAttribute: 5}, 
   hideTitle: false, 
   template: "football-news", customProperties: {template: "list-view"}
};
var arr = convertToArray(obj);
var filterarr = arr.filter(a => a instanceof Object && ("NewsID" in a));
console.log(filterarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var arr = [
  {NewsID: 90, AnotherAttribute: 5},
  {NewsID: 90, AnotherAttribute: 5},
  {NewsID: 90, AnotherAttribute: 5},
  false,
  "football-news",
  {template: "list-view"}
];

var result = arr.filter(item => item instanceof Object && ("NewsID" in item));
console.log(result);
```