# check if key index exists in an associative array Angularjs javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From the below json data how can I check if key **"type_1"** of **"no_2"** exists, if doesnt exists to push `{"p_id": "24","subcat_id": "2","name": "ok"}` to the **"type_1"** of **"no_2"** array object.

How does key index and array push works here

```
{
  "no_1": {
    "orderNumber": "no_1",
    "billing_order_id": "1",
    "orderArray": {
      "type 2": [
        {
          "p_id": "25",
          "subcat_id": "2",
          "name": "fine"
        },
        {
          "p_id": "34",
          "subcat_id": "2",
          "name": "not ok"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "no_2": {
    "orderNumber": "no_2",
    "billing_order_id": "1",
    "orderArray": {
      "type_1": [
        {
          "p_id": "6",
          "subcat_id": "1",
          "name": "hello"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Checking if a key exists in a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @GuyIncognito No. That question is not answering my problem. Here its an associative array.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have associative arrays. You have an object.

Answer (score 0):

I think  this is what  you're  trying to do.
(Most JavaScript code is not structured quite this way, but the sample code is verbose for clarity.)

```js
const
  myObj = getObj(),
  keyToCheck = "no_3",
  myArr = [],

  myKeys = Object.keys(myObj), // `.keys` is as static method of Object
  keyToPush = myKeys[0], // gets first key in list
  valueToPush = myObj[keyToPush], // gets value from this key in obj
  fullObjToPush = {}; // makes a new empty object

fullObjToPush[keyToPush] = valueToPush; // Makes a new property in obj w/ key and val


// pushes object to array if `keyToCheck` is not found
if(myKeys.includes(keyToCheck)){  /* do nothing */ }
else{ myArr.push(fullObjToPush); }

// prints result
console.log("myArr now contains this object:");
console.log(myArr);

// provides original object
function getObj(){
  return {
    "no_1": { "orderNumber": "no_1", "billing_order_id": "1" },
    "no_2": { "orderNumber": "no_2", "billing_order_id": "1" }
  }
}
```