# How I can check if a object array key exists in Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following array

```
 let newArray = [
    {
      "conterTop": {
        "uncategroized": [item1, item2, item3],
        "categroized": [item4, item5]
      }
    },
    {
      "flooring": {
        "uncategroized": [item1, item2, item3],
        "categroized": [item4, item5]
      }
    }
]
```

I'm pushing countertop & flooring on runtime. Now I need to check if countertop already exists in **newArray**, it should not push countertop again. I have tried **newArray.includes()** but it's not working. Please any suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript) Specifically look at the 2nd top answer as it deals with non primitive types

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57659626/12960148

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array to look for your matching key and check the length of the filtered array. If the length is greater than 0, it exists. If not, it doesn't.

```
newArray.filter(x => return typeof(x.countertop) !== "undefined").length > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I just filtered out every value that doesn't have `counterTop` and check if any value left

```js
let newArray = [{
    "conterTop": {
      "uncategroized": [1, 2, 3],
      "categroized": [4, 5]
    }
  },
  {
    "flooring": {
      "uncategroized": [1, 2, 3],
      "categroized": [4, 5]
    }
  }
];

let isCounterTopExists = newArray.filter(x => x.conterTop).length > 0
console.log(isCounterTopExists);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is for:

```js
let newArray = [
    {
      "conterTop": {}
    },
    {
      "flooring": {}
    }
];

let testArray = [
  {
    "flooring": {}
  }
];

const testArrayResult = testArray.some(obj => obj.conterTop);
const newArrayResult = newArray.some(obj => obj.conterTop);

console.log("testArray has 'conterTop':", testArrayResult);
console.log("newArray has 'conterTop':", newArrayResult);
```