# How to check for the property in Chai inside the array of objects

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, integration-testing, chai

How to check, with Chai, for a property inside the array of objects. My array of objects is like this:

```
const myObj = [ {fName: 'abc', lName: 'xyz'}, {fName: 'efg', lName: 'lmn'}, ... ]
```

I want to check that each object must have the property `fName` and `lName` irrespective of their value!

P.S. : I know one library named as chai-things, and with that we can achieve this, however if I only want to use chai then ?

Comment: This answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object . Loop through the elements and check if the property is in the dictionary

Comment: agreed. I can loop through it manually, however, I do not want to do that. Anything available in the Chai framework to achieve this?

Comment: You can solve this with chai-things https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-things . After installation do `foods.should.all.have.property('fName', 'lName')`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a for loop or the [chai-things](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-things) library, you can use the [deep equal expectation](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_eql) to compare the entire array in a single assertion:

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;

const myObj = [ {fName: 'abc', lName: 'xyz'}, {fName: 'efg', lName: 'lmn'} ];

describe('Test Suite', () => {
  it('MyObj Test', function() {
    expect(myObj).to.eql([ {fName: 'abc', lName: 'xyz'}, {fName: 'efg', lName: 'lmn'}]);
  });
});
```

If you change the second object and run the tests, you'll see a very specific error:

```
AssertionError: expected [ Array(2) ] to deeply equal [ Array(2) ]
  + expected - actual

       "lName": "xyz"
     }
     {
       "fName": "efg"
  -    "lName": "lmn"
  +    "lName": "lmn2"
     }
   ]
```

---

Or you must write all expectations explicitily:

```
expect(myObj).to.be.an('array');
expect(myObj[0]).to.have.property('fName');
expect(myObj[0]).to.have.property('lName');
expect(myObj[1]).to.have.property('fName');
expect(myObj[1]).to.have.property('lName');
// and so on...
```