# Easier way to check for existence before using a JSON value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting (sometimes) an attribute in a JSON response called `smallThumbnail`.  It may or may not exist... along with parent and grandparent properties `imageLinks` and `volumeInfo`. Is there a cleaner way than this to prevent me from using a `smallThumbnail` value that doesn't exist and throwing errors?

```
<img src={option.volumeInfo &&
   option.volumeInfo.imageLinks &&
   option.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail ?
      option.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail :
      "https://up.quizlet.com/1hbijs-gYV7D-256s.jpg"} 
    width="40" height="40" />
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), you can write this pretty cleanly:

```js
<img src={option.volumeInfo?.imageLinks?.smallThumbnail
      || "https://up.quizlet.com/1hbijs-gYV7D-256s.jpg"} 
    width="40" height="40" />
```

Basically how `a?.b` works is "if `a` exists, do the rest of the expression, otherwise return undefined". By chaining this several times and combining with `||` as shown above, we have a nice one-liner with a default value.

Since you are using JSX, you're most likely using something like Babel/Webpack that can automatically transform optional chaining to "old JavaScript" to increase compatibility for older browsers or browser versions.

Comment: I've used such a thing in C#, didn't know about it in JS.  Very convenient, thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Does this not also throw errors?

If it's supported by your node version, I think this is the best solution: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

If it's not, check out this answer:
[Checking if a key exists in a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object)