# Return all nested objects with specific keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested-object

I have an array of objects in Javascript:

```
[
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 4},
{d: 10, a: 9, r: 2},
{c: 5, e: 2, j: 41}
]
```

I would like to return an array of all the objects that have the key name `c` by using the key name for the lookup.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Iterate the array and check, if the object has the key. If it does, add it to the new array.

Comment: @Geshode it might be best to make use of inherent array methods such as `filter()` for something like this.

Comment: @dqhendricks I was just trying to nudge OP into a direction, so that they can start to do the work themself, instead of me writing the code for them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1098040/4294399

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter method and hasOwnProperty

```
const arr = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 4},{d: 10, a: 9, r: 2},{c: 5, e: 2, j: 41}];
const myArray = array.filter(e => e.hasOwnProperty('c'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`.filter` + `in` operator

```
var arr = [
    {a: 1, b: 2, c: 4},
    {d: 10, a: 9, r: 2},
    {c: 5, e: 2, j: 41}
];
var result = arr.filter((x) => 'c' in x);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `filter()`, and maybe `hasOwnProperty()` or another way to check if the property is present on the object.

```js
const myarray = [
    { a: 1, b: 2, c: 4 },
    { d: 10, a: 9, r: 2 },
    { c: 5, e: 2, j: 41 }
];

const processedarray = myarray.filter( item => item.hasOwnProperty( 'c' ) );

console.log( processedarray );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

```js
const data = [{
    a: 1, b: 2, c: 4
  },
  {
    d: 10, a: 9, r: 2
  },
  {
    c: 5,  e: 2, j: 41
  }
];

const filtered = (arr, prop) =>
  arr.filter(a => a.hasOwnProperty(prop));
  
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(filtered(data, 'c'))
);
```

---

If you want to return an array of objects with multiple specific keys, you can combine it with [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
const data = [{
    a: 1, b: 2, c: 4
  },
  {
    d: 10, a: 9, r: 2
  },
  {
    c: 5,  e: 2, j: 41
  }
];
  
const filtered = (arr, ...props) =>
  arr.filter(a => props.some(prop => a.hasOwnProperty(prop)));

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(filtered(data, 'b', 'j'))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to loop through the array to check if the object has a key named `c`

```js
var arr = [
    { a: 1, b: 2, c: 4 },
    { d: 10, a: 9, r: 2 },
    { c: 5, e: 2, j: 41 }
]

// they both do the same job
var result = arr.filter(item => Object.keys(item).some(key => key === 'c'))
var filtered = arr.filter(item => item.hasOwnProperty('c'))


console.log(result);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: `.some(key => key.indexOf('c') > -1)` will be true for keys *containing* the letter 'c'.  I think you want `.some(key => key === 'c')`

Comment: you are right, but i guess he got the idea, I will change the answer @danh

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method along with [`Object.hasOwn()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn).

Live Demo **:**

```js
const arr = [
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 4},
{d: 10, a: 9, r: 2},
{c: 5, e: 2, j: 41}
];

const res = arr.filter(obj => Object.hasOwn(obj, 'c'));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is My answer. Thank you

```js
const arr = [
  {a: 1, b: 2, c: 4},
  {d: 10, a: 9, r: 2},
  {c: 5, e: 2, j: 41}
]

const filter = (arr, byKey) => {
  return arr.filter((ob) => {
    return Object.keys(ob).includes(byKey)
  })
}

console.log(filter(arr, 'c'))
```