# How to check if a certain key name exist in json object in React app

Tags: reactjs, json, response

I create this custom hook in my React app. It should return a `boolean`.

```
const useFetchResponse = (url: string) => {
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchResponse = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      console.log(response);
      
      const obj = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        console.log(await response.json());
        setIsValid(true);
      }

      return response;
    };

    fetchResponse().then((res) => res);
  }, []);

  return isValid;
};

export default useFetchResponse;
```

When I log `const obj = await response.json();` it returns: `{"keyName":"some=key"}`.

How do I create a condition to check if `response.json()` has a key named `keyName`?

Is that for example `console.log('keyName' in obj) // true`?
Do you see more things which I can improve and refactor?

Answer (score 0):

Let assume you get response as follow

```
let response = {
  a:'data1',
  b:'data2',
  c:'data3'
};
```

Then you can extract keys from object as below:

```
let keyOnly = Object.keys(response)); // output will be ["a","b","c"]
```

then you can check if your require value includes on above array or not as below: Assuming if you want to check if `"b"` is included or not

```
let checkKey = keyOnly.includes(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check whether an object has a certain property or not, the `in` operator is fine.

```
const obj = { a: 1 };
'a' in obj // return true
'b' in obj // return false
```

About improvements

- it's better to save all fetch states, [not only valid or not](https://medium.com/@selbekk/handling-data-fetching-with-state-machines-4e25b6366d9). And you should wrap request with [try/catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block. For example:

```
const [fetchState, setFetchState] = useState('pending');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchResponse = async () => {
      try {
        setFetchState('loading');
        const response = await fetch(url);
        console.log(response);
      
        const obj = await response.json();

        if (response.ok) {
          console.log(await response.json());
          setFetchState('success');
        }

        return response;
      } catch (error) {
        setFetchState('failed')
      }
      
    };

    fetchResponse().then((res) => res);
  }, []);

  return fetchState;
};
```

- `fetchResponse();` would be enough.  `fetchResponse().then((res) => res);` is unnecessary.
- [optional] You could use libraries to making requests, like an [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios). That would be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

`in` is slower than below way.

```
const isValid = obj[`keyname`] !== undefined
```

Check more detail in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object)